# setting params and multipart entity in HttpClient

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, httpconnection

I using HttpClient and httpost to upload my image file along with some parameters.

My code looks like

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("xyz.com");

ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","Temp"));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","12345"));
httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
File imgFile = new File("C:\test.img");            
FileBody imgFileBody = new FileBody(imgFile);
entity.addPart("multipartcontent", imgFileBody); //No i18n  
httpost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpost);
```

Am not getting the param values in server. Am i doing anything wrong. Please guide me.

Comment: Refer to the following example code http://stackoverflow.com/a/22356480/1434097

Answer (score 0):

```
httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
...  
httpost.setEntity(entity);
```

The multipart entity overrides the URL encoded one completely discarding its content.

You should add param values to the multipart entity as one or several body parts