# How to send multi parameter in form data while uploading a file to server on Android?

Tags: java, android, file-upload, multipartform-data

I need to send the multi parameter in form data while uploading a file to server on Android. I used this [code for uploading a files to server.](http://code.google.com/p/android-project-programe/source/browse/upload2server/src/uit/edu/upload2server/HttpFileUploader.java?r=81) Here my doubt is how to send multi parameters in form data?

Comment: Holy crap, don't use that code. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038409/how-to-send-http-post-request-and-recieve-response/3038747#3038747) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919512/android-multipart-upload) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use the Apache HTTP client stuff.  Put a `List<NameValuePair>` of your desired values into a `UrlEncodedFormEntity`, set it as the entity in an instance of `HttpPost`, and POST away.

[Apache HTTP Client JavaDocs for Android are here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)

Comment: @bharath I thought you wanted to send form data.  There's a `ByteArrayEntity` and a `FileEntity` if that's what you want to send.  And an `InputStreamEntity` if you don't necessarily want to load up everything in memory first.