# Upload Image in Custom Object using Multipart Form Data In Android

Tags: android, multipartform-data

I need to create the uploaded structure of data as : 
    {
        "authentication_token":"some_token",
        "user": {
            "fname": "fname",
            "lname": "lname",
            "avatar": "image-file"
            "location": "location"
        }
    }

The "avatar" is actually an Image File (profile image of the user).

I've tried to create the structure using Apache's MultipartEntity class, adding FileBody & StringBody objects. For key-value pairing, I've used NameValuePair. But I'm not able to add the User object separately. I don't know how to.

I looked for answers in these links : 
[MultiPartEntity along with plain text in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081831/multipartentity-along-with-plain-text-in-android)
[Android Multipart Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919512/android-multipart-upload)
[How to send multiple images to server using MultipartEntity from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422541/how-to-send-multiple-images-to-server-using-multipartentity-from-android)
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/08/16/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-one-request-along-with-other-string-parameters-in-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so much research, I've finally found a working solution, don't know whether it is the best one. 
I had to use Apache's MultipartEntity and its helper classes.

Here's the code :

```
ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
BasicNameValuePair bn;

bn = new BasicNameValuePair("authentication_token", app.getSystemValue("authentication_token"));
nameValuePairs.add(bn);
bn = new BasicNameValuePair("fname", user.getFname());
nameValuePairs.add(bn);
bn = new BasicNameValuePair("lname", user.getLname());
nameValuePairs.add(bn);
bn = new BasicNameValuePair("location", user.getLocation());
nameValuePairs.add(bn);
bn = new BasicNameValuePair("avatar", user.getAvatar());
nameValuePairs.add(bn);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.getParams().setParameter("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
client.getParams().setParameter("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;");
client.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", Integer.valueOf(TIMEOUT_WAIT_TO_CONNECT));
client.getParams().setParameter("http.connection.timeout", Integer.valueOf(TIMEOUT_WAIT_FOR_DATA));

MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
int i=0;

for (BasicNameValuePair nameValuePair : nameValuePairs) {
    if (nameValuePair.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("avatar")) {
        File imgFile = new File(nameValuePair.getValue());
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(imgFile, "profile.jpeg", "image/jpeg", "UTF-8");
        multipartEntity.addPart("user[avatar]", fileBody);
    } 
    else {
        if (nameValuePair.getValue()!=null) {
            if (i==0) {
                multipartEntity.addPart(nameValuePair.getName(), new StringBody(nameValuePair.getValue()));
            }
            else {
                multipartEntity.addPart("user[" + nameValuePair.getName() + "]", new StringBody(nameValuePair.getValue()));
            }
        }
    }
    i++;
}

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(serviceUri);
post.setEntity(multipartEntity);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

I hope it helps someone in need.