# Android - Upload file and send vars to php form

Tags: php, android, file-upload, http-post, httpclient

I have a PHP file which takes as input a file and one or more vars, all given by post method.
I have to do a HTTP POST Request in Android to that PHP file, sending it file (image) and vars.
I know how to send only the file ([post file](http://getablogger.blogspot.it/2008/01/android-how-to-post-file-to-php-server.html)) or the data/vars ([post data](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)), but how can I modify these snippets to do both actions (send file + send data) on the same request?
Thanks

Edit: The sending form is something about this:

```
<form action="receive.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></p>
    <p><input name="firstVar" type="text" /></p>
    <p><input name="secondVar" type="text" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="send" /></p>
</form>
```

So, in receiving side, I will have my vars on `$_POST["firstVar"]` and `$_POST["secondVar"]`, and the uploaded file on `$_FILES["file"]`.

Comment: show us the form. but the regular form data will be in the $_POST\$_GET var and the file date in the $_FILES var

Comment: Why do you need a php form for an android request?

Comment: @michal they're asking how to send from Android to a website (the fact it's PHP irrelevant)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post multipart request with Android SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017414/post-multipart-request-with-android-sdk)