# How to send multiple images to server using MultipartEntity from android

Tags: android

I am sending Images and Text to a PHP webservice using the following code.

```
try {       
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
            HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

    entity.addPart("files[]",
            new ByteArrayBody(data, "myImage.jpg"));

    entity.addPart("message0", new StringBody(caption.getText()
            .toString()));

    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
            localContext);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

    String sResponse = reader.readLine();
    return sResponse;
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(ImageUpload.this, e.getMessage(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
    return null;
}
    }
```

It works perfectly. But this is only for one image. I want to send 5 images.

Example: `Image1 - Text1`
`Image2  - Text2` etc..

So I am confused about how to store 5 images one by one and then on button click, send these images and text associated with them to the server.

I am getting images from the phone's camera.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                    PICK_IMAGE);


public void onActivityResult_photo(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (data != null) {
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            display(mImageCaptureUri);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(CustomTabActivity.mTabHost.getContext(),
                    "No photo selected..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}


private String display(Uri mImageCaptureUri2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String base64string = null;
    try {

        if (mImageCaptureUri2 != null) {

            System.gc();

            selectedImagePath = getPath(mImageCaptureUri2);

            File filenew = new File(selectedImagePath);
            int file_size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(filenew
                    .length() / 1024));
            if (file_size <= 10000) {
                PD1 = ProgressDialog.show(
                        CustomTabActivity.mTabHost.getContext(), "",
                        "Loading...");
                Handler refresh = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

                refresh.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        PD1.setCancelable(true);
                        Bitmap newbitmap;
                        newbitmap = decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        newbitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50,
                                bs);
                        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        img.setImageBitmap(newbitmap);
                        byte[] abc = bitmapToByteArray(newbitmap);
                        if (txt_phototext.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                            submit.put(abc, "");
                        } else {
                            submit.put(abc, txt_phototext.getText()
                                    .toString());

                            // executeMultipartPost();
                        }
                        PD1.dismiss();

                    }
                });

            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        CustomTabActivity.mTabHost.getContext());
                alertbox.setMessage("Take Image Size Less than 10 MB");
                alertbox.setNeutralButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                                    int arg1) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                alertbox.show();
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("===============NULL========");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return base64string;
}


    static Bitmap decodeFile(String str) {
    try {
        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(str), null, o);

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale++;
        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(str), null,
                o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}

public static byte[] bitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /* ignored for PNG */, bos);
    byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
    return bitmapdata;
}
```

Comment: [Uploading multiple files to server](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/08/16/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-one-request-along-with-other-string-parameters-in-android/) [The jar files needs to add for this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017414/post-multipart-request-with-android-sdk) this helps for you in solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
val reqEntity = MultipartEntity()
imagePaths.foreach { path ->
    reqEntity.addPart("path$i", FileBody(file));
}
val client: HttpClient = DefaultHttpClient()
val post = HttpPost(url)
post.setEntity(reqEntity);
val response: HttpResponse = client.execute(post)
```

Answer (score 0):

And make sure that your directory or folder in server is Executable, Writable and Readable. I had this as the major problem. This is called 777 permission.. Believe me, this is as important as other things to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the `post_max_size` of your php.ini file in WAMP server

Answer (score 0):

**For full detail please have a look on my post** [Click here](http://smartandrodev.co.in/?p=63#more-63)

**its quite difficult to send multiple images to server using MultipartEntity. I did search for this but didn't find any right solution then i made my own way to send multiple images to server**
*, here i send array of selected paths to  asynctask and in asynctask i sent images to server*

**Calling Asysnctask Function-**
new Upload_Multiple.excute(Array_of_Path[]))

```
    Private class Upload_Multiple_img extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... paths_array) {



        String data = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < paths_array.length; i++) {

            //  get_Picture_bitmap() returns bitmap by passing path of image 
             //   get_Picture_bitmap() is mentioned below. 
            Bitmap bitmap = get_Picture_bitmap(paths_array[i]);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()); // convert

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            String server_funtion_url="...serveraddres"+funtion_at_server"";
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(server_funtion_url); // server

            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

            obj_SP = ImagePicker.this.getSharedPreferences("Eperty", 0);

            String id_prop = obj_SP.getString("new_prop_id", "");

            String Image_Name =
                    + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg";
// image is a key which is used at server end to get this 
            reqEntity.addPart("image", Image_Name, in);

            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                System.out.println("FFFF== " + data);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        ConstantData.ToastAlert(ImagePicker.this,
                "Images Uploaded successfully");

    }
}
```

//);

- For compressing the images and getting bitmap for i made below funtion*

  ```
  public Bitmap get_Picture_bitmap(String imagePath) {

  long size_file = getFileSize(new File(imagePath));

  size_file = (size_file) / 1000;// in Kb now
  int ample_size = 1;

  if (size_file <= 250) {

      System.out.println("SSSSS1111= " + size_file);
      ample_size = 2;

  } else if (size_file > 251 && size_file < 1500) {

      System.out.println("SSSSS2222= " + size_file);
      ample_size = 4;

  } else if (size_file >= 1500 && size_file < 3000) {

      System.out.println("SSSSS3333= " + size_file);
      ample_size = 8;

  } else if (size_file >= 3000 && size_file <= 4500) {

      System.out.println("SSSSS4444= " + size_file);
      ample_size = 12;

  } else if (size_file >= 4500) {

      System.out.println("SSSSS4444= " + size_file);
      ample_size = 16;
  }

  Bitmap bitmap = null;

  BitmapFactory.Options bitoption = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  bitoption.inSampleSize = ample_size;

  Bitmap bitmapPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bitoption);

  ExifInterface exif = null;
  try {
      exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
  } catch (IOException e) {
      // Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  int orientation = exif
          .getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
  Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

  if ((orientation == 3)) {
      matrix.postRotate(180);
      bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapPhoto, 0, 0,
              bitmapPhoto.getWidth(), bitmapPhoto.getHeight(), matrix,
              true);

  } else if (orientation == 6) {
      matrix.postRotate(90);
      bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapPhoto, 0, 0,
              bitmapPhoto.getWidth(), bitmapPhoto.getHeight(), matrix,
              true);

  } else if (orientation == 8) {
      matrix.postRotate(270);
      bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapPhoto, 0, 0,
              bitmapPhoto.getWidth(), bitmapPhoto.getHeight(), matrix,
              true);

  } else {
      matrix.postRotate(0);
      bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapPhoto, 0, 0,
              bitmapPhoto.getWidth(), bitmapPhoto.getHeight(), matrix,
              true);

  }

  return bitmap;
  ```

  }
  **
- Server end Code *

  ```
  $target_dir = "../webadmin/user_image/";
  $target_dir = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["user_img"]["name"]);
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir))
    {
       $msg = "The file ". basename($result[0]). " has been uploaded.";
       $send_arr['success'] = 1;
       $send_arr['message'] = $msg;
       echo json_encode($send_arr);
    }
  else 
    {
       $msg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
       $send_arr['success'] = 0;
       $send_arr['message'] = $msg;
       echo json_encode($send_arr);
    }
  ```

Comment: Why you can't just create array of json object of your images to base64 and post to server and at your server api read those images convert to byte and use as image.

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't just create array of json object of your images to base64 and post to server and at your server api read those images convert to byte and use as image.
Check my answe and try to implement.
[In Android how to post data to webservice which is created in WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205693/in-android-how-to-post-data-to-webservice-which-is-created-in-wcf/37206061#37206061)

And the images you are getting from camera store them in uri in sdcard and letter read them. You can assign image name sequntialy. And read them from uri.

Comment: because for larger images base 64 string can be really large and sometimes they don't get send completely. So that's why uploading them as a file is a better option.

Answer (score -1):

Please find the below method...here i m sending mutiple image file using AQUERY. The best lib to perform all background network related task.(Like AJAX).

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/

```
   public void uploadImageFile( String filePath,
            String message) {

        Context context = ApplicationContextProvider.getContext();
        String url = SERVER_URL + "/user/uploadImageFile";


            try {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Uploading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                String compressedFile = CommonUtilities.compressImage(filePath,
                        context);

                Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();


                File imageFile = new File(compressedFile);
                byte[] imageBytes1 = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(imageFile);
                params.put("imageBytes", imageBytes1);
                params.put("message",URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8"));


                AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);
                aq.ajax(url, params, JSONObject.class,
                        new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void callback(String url, JSONObject json,
                                    AjaxStatus status) {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        ApplicationContextProvider.getContext(),
                                        "Uploaded successfully",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                            }
                        });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

    }
```