# Upload multiple images at a time from one web service call in Android?

Tags: android, image-uploading, wcf-rest

I am working in an application where I have to upload multiple images at a time from RESTFUL web service URL.

I have converted the images in Base64 forma but now getting problem in creating Array of images.

Please suggest me, how can I send **multiple Images** at a time by using **RESTFUL JSON SERVICE URL**.

Comment: Where is your code which you are trying ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MultipartEntity` to sent multiple images on server. I have already done this. Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422541/how-to-send-multiple-images-to-server-using-multipartentity-from-android).