# Android, it failed to upload an image to server

Tags: java, android

I am trying to upload an image file using multipart method to the server.

Here are my codes.

```
package com.example.test_multipart;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        TestAsyncTask asyncTask = new TestAsyncTask();

        @Override
        public void onClick(android.view.View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            new TestAsyncTask().execute();

        }

    });

}

public class TestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<HttpResponse, Integer, Long> {
    private ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    long totalSize;

    String url = "http://bridgecall.co.kr:5000/apis/settings/profile_update";
    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(HttpResponse... arg0) {

        // Register parameters
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("phone", "01030195208");
        params.put("name", "YUJIHYN");


        Map<String, File> fileParams = new HashMap<String, File>();

        File f = new File("/DCIM/Camera/test.jpg");
        fileParams.put("file", f);

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            httpPost.setHeader("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");


            CustomMultipartEntity multipart = new CustomMultipartEntity(
                    new ProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long transferred) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            publishProgress((int) transferred);
                        }
                    });

            // Params 
            for (String strKey : params.keySet()) {
                StringBody body = new StringBody(params.get(strKey)
                        .toString());
                multipart.addPart(strKey, body);
            }

            // attach a file
            for (String keys : fileParams.keySet()) {
                multipart.addPart(keys, new FileBody(fileParams.get(keys)));

            }

            totalSize = multipart.getContentLength();
            mDialog.setMax((int) totalSize);
            httpPost.setEntity(multipart);


            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);




            Log.v("checkcheckcheckcheck ", "checkcheckcheckcheck");
            HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();



            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              String line = null;
              while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               sb.append(line).append("\n");
              }
              is.close();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0L;
        }

        return 0L;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        mDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) { // ui.
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mDialog.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mDialog.setOnCancelListener(cancelListener);
        mDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
        mDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        // Progress update
        mDialog.setProgress((int) progress[0]);

    }

    OnCancelListener cancelListener = new OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };
}
```

}

It doesn't work after this line.

```
Log.v("checkcheckcheckcheck ", "checkcheckcheckcheck");
```

I get 400 error from the server.

It works fine if I upload an image on HTML. Can you see what is the problem?

Comment: [Did you check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422541/how-to-send-multiple-images-to-server-using-multipartentity-from-android)???

Comment: Are you passing the correct file path?

Comment: @Prince I checked the page. still.. it's not working

Comment: @Jake what are errors???