# Posting image and string data as multipart from android to server

Tags: android

### I am trying to post data as `multipart` using `post method` from android client to server

---

- Image part is working fine
- I am not able to get the data from edittext to be able to send as
  another key value

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button submit;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    InputStream is;

    EditText name;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SUBMIT_BUTTON_ID);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new MainTest().execute();


            }
        });
    }



    /**
     * Method to post the image to the server.
     * U will have to change the url which will accept the image data.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public void postImageData() {


        try
        {

            Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image); 
            String NAME = name.getText().toString();

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:7002/Details/");
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            try{
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmapOrg.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
                byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "image.jpg");
                reqEntity.addPart("key", bab);
                reqEntity.addPart("key1", NAME);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                //Log.v("Exception in Image", ""+e);
                reqEntity.addPart("picture", new StringBody(""));
            }
            postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);       
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getStackTrace();
        }


    }
    public class MainTest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            postImageData();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // data=jobj.toString();
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="168dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.41"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="101dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="195dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:ems="10" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SUBMIT_BUTTON_ID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"
        android:text="SUBMIT" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**I am getting the error in the line** ::

```
reqEntity.addPart("key1", NAME);
```

**as**

```
The method addPart(String, ContentBody) in the type MultipartEntity is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)
```

---

**how can i overcome this !**

Comment: where is `reqEntity` declared and what is `NAME`?

Comment: @Raghunandan ..... NAME is the variable name .... i am trying to get the values of edittext and pass it here ( i am a noob) .... i am not able to determine how to send another key value along with image .... can u guide me please

Comment: @Prince ....... I have updated the answer ..... thats all the code i have

Comment: @smriti3 why always .... unwanted.

Comment: @smriti3 this is working code for me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422541/how-to-send-multiple-images-to-server-using-multipartentity-from-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
String NAME = name.getText().toString();
reqEntity.addPart("key1", NAME);
```

`public void addPart(String name,ContentBody contentBody)`

You have wrong params for `addPart`. The second param should be ContentBody

So change to

```
 reqEntity.addPart("key1", new StringBody(NAME));
```

Reference

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ContentBody.html

Check the below if it helps

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-making-http-requests/

Comment: @smriti3 did you check how you receive on the server side. As was in your previous case that might be a problem. Check the second link in my post.

Comment: @smriti3 do check the docs for MultiPartEntity and there is no need for ..... in your comments. Put a single `.`.

Comment: @smriti3 i see nothing wrong on the android side other than the suggested edit.

Comment: @ Raghunandan ...... i have come up with a different approach to solve this .... please have a look at this link ...... http://stackoverflow.com/q/20565971/2901850

Comment: @smriti3 surely problem on server side. You need to handle the request at the server end. I am pretty sure android code is alright

Comment: @ Raghunandan ......... after spending one day on this .... i resolved this ..... problem was on the server side ... as u guided me :)

Comment: @smriti3 - I am glad that StringBody solved your problem. Keep coding and help the community!

Answer (score 1):

The above code snippet gives error because if you want to send text in the multi-part then wrap inside the `StringBody` class.

Do this

```
reqEntity.addPart("key1", new StringBody("Your String goes here..."));
```

instead of

```
reqEntity.addPart("key1", NAME);
```

Comment: reqEntity.addPart("key1", NAME); What is Name:-is this String or else?