# In Android how to post data to webservice which is created in WCF?

Tags: c#, android, json, web-services, wcf

I am new to C# webservice developed using WCF framework. And I have to post data in URL. My URL is something like as **http://www.example.com/abc/DGLC.svc/login** and I have to pass data using post method. And parameters are as follow in following format.

{

"UserName": "Admin",

"Password": "abcd1234",

"DiviceType": "Windows",

"UniqueID": "deviceidneedtopasshere"

}

Please help me, how to implement this kind of WS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what you have tried?

Comment: @VishalMokal yes it is a SOAP call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a class representing the fields of your json. and in your webservice pass this in method parameter. and run this method in your backthread (asyncTask)

```
  public static String postAPIResponse(String url, String data) {

        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        InputStream inputStream;
        StringBuffer responses = null;
        try {
            URL urlObject = new URL(url);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) (urlObject.openConnection());

            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(data.getBytes().length));
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
            if (Cookie.getCookie() != null)
                con.addRequestProperty("Cookie", Cookie.getCookie());

            con.setUseCaches(false);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);

            //Send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(data);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            //Get Response
            if (con.getResponseCode() == 200) {


                InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line;
                responses = new StringBuffer();
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    responses.append(line);
                }
                rd.close();

            } else {

                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(con.getErrorStream());
                return convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            assert con != null;
            con.disconnect();
        }
        return responses != null ? responses.toString() : "";
    }


static public String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line;
    String result = "";
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        result += line;
    }
        /* Close Stream */
    inputStream.close();
    return result;
}
```

where data is string of json object new JsonObject.accumulate()... etc to map with your service object