# Replacing PostMethod with HttpPost in Android

Tags: android, apache, weibo

While integrating Weibo's Android SDK into an app, I discovered the `HttpClient` class it contains uses an obsolete library that Android dislikes intensely (in fact I think they just pasted a Java SDK into an Android Eclipse project and shipped it).  This library only seems to perform a single function within Weibo, which is to assemble POST requests (using the `PostMethod` class) and send them to the Weibo server.  I blithely assumed it would be relatively straightforward to replace this with the standard Apache `HttpPost`, which is included in Android.

Unfortunately the `Part` class seems to have no straightforward equivalent.  At least some of the `Part`s could be replaced by `BasicNameValuePair` classes, but there is a custom `Part` defined by Weibo that looks more like a `ByteArrayEntity`.

Examining the two methods called `multPartUrl` (not a typo) in

[Weibo's source for HttpClient](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Client/sipadan-weibo/weibo4andriod/http/HttpClient.java.htm)

the first of which is reproduced here (the second is very similar but pastes in a different type of content):

```
public Response multPartURL(String url,  PostParameter[] params,ImageItem item,boolean authenticated) throws WeiboException{
  PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);
  try {
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient client = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient();
    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Part[] parts=null;
    if(params==null){
      parts=new Part[1];
    }else{
      parts=new Part[params.length+1];
    }
    if (params != null ) {
      int i=0;
        for (PostParameter entry : params) {
          parts[i++]=new StringPart( entry.getName(),(String)entry.getValue());
      }
        parts[parts.length-1]=new ByteArrayPart(item.getContent(), item.getName(), item.getImageType());
      }
    post.setRequestEntity( new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, post.getParams()) );
     List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();

     if (authenticated) {
              if (basic == null && oauth == null) {
              }
              String authorization = null;
              if (null != oauth) {
                  // use OAuth
                  authorization = oauth.generateAuthorizationHeader( "POST" , url, params, oauthToken);
              } else if (null != basic) {
                  // use Basic Auth
                  authorization = this.basic;
              } else {
                  throw new IllegalStateException(
                          "Neither user ID/password combination nor OAuth consumer key/secret combination supplied");
              }
              headers.add(new Header("Authorization", authorization));
              log("Authorization: " + authorization);
          }
      client.getHostConfiguration().getParams().setParameter("http.default-headers", headers);
    client.executeMethod(post);

    Response response=new Response();
    response.setResponseAsString(post.getResponseBodyAsString());
    response.setStatusCode(post.getStatusCode());

    log("multPartURL URL:" + url + ", result:" + response + ", time:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));
      return response;
  } catch (Exception ex) {
     throw new WeiboException(ex.getMessage(), ex, -1);
  } finally {
    post.releaseConnection();
  }
}
```

it can be seen that a number of `Part`s are added to a `MultiPartRequestEntity`, the last of which is a byte array or a file.

- What (if anything) is the equivalent to `MultiPartRequestEntity` in the more up to date Apache libraries?
- Is there a way to add a byte array to a `UrlEncodedFormEntity`?
- Is there, alternatively, a way to add name-value pairs to a `ByteArrayEntity`?
- Is there something else I am missing completely?

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I've found so far seems to be based on the answer to this question:

[Post multipart request with Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017414/post-multipart-request-with-android-sdk)

This shows where to get the non-obsolete replacements for the libraries used by Weibo.

I've then replaced

```
Part[] parts=null;
if(params==null){
  parts=new Part[1];
}else{
  parts=new Part[params.length+1];
}
if (params != null ) {
  int i=0;
    for (PostParameter entry : params) {
      parts[i++]=new StringPart( entry.getName(),(String)entry.getValue());
  }
    parts[parts.length-1]=new ByteArrayPart(item.getContent(), item.getName(), item.getImageType());
  }
post.setRequestEntity( new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, post.getParams()) );
```

with

```
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
        if(params!=null) {
            for (PostParameter entry : params) {
                entity.addPart(entry.getName(), new StringBody(entry.getValue()));
            }
        }

        entity.addPart("filename", new ByteArrayBody(item.getContent(), item.getImageType(), item.getName()));
```

I'm not 100% certain about the last line as I've based that on Weibo's own class, which sets a `filename` parameter; however, it could well be called something else, though what is not clear.

I've then replaced the `HttpClient` with an `AndroidHttpClient` and used standard `AndroidHttpClient` methods to get the status code and an `InputStream` with the content from the entity; this stream, I am passing into the Weibo `Response` class and reading into the string it has as its main member.  These assumptions may be wrong but I will continue to look into it.