# How to send a “multipart/form-data” POST in Android with Volley

Tags: android, http, android-volley

Has anyone been able to accomplish sending a `multipart/form-data` POST in Android with Volley yet? I have had no success trying to upload an `image/png` using a POST request to our server and am curious if anyone has.

I believe the default way to do this would be to override `public byte[] getPostBody()` in the `Request.java` class and attach the `File` there with a blank Header key for the boundary. However, converting my file to a `String` for the `Map<String, String> postParams` and then having it encoded again seems obtuse and not really elegant.  Also I've been unsuccessful in my attempts. This is really the only thing holding us back from switching to this library.

Anyway, all thoughts and answers are extremely appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I might be wrong on this but I think you need to implement your own `com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpStack` for this because the default ones (`HurlStack` if version > Gingerbread or `HttpClientStack`) don't deal with `multipart/form-data`.

**Edit:**

And indeed I was wrong. I was able to do it using `MultipartEntity` in Request like this:

```
public class MultipartRequest extends Request<String> {

    private MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

    private static final String FILE_PART_NAME = "file";
    private static final String STRING_PART_NAME = "text";

    private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
    private final File mFilePart;
    private final String mStringPart;

    public MultipartRequest(String url, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, Response.Listener<String> listener, File file, String stringPart)
    {
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

        mListener = listener;
        mFilePart = file;
        mStringPart = stringPart;
        buildMultipartEntity();
    }

    private void buildMultipartEntity()
    {
        entity.addPart(FILE_PART_NAME, new FileBody(mFilePart));
        try
        {
            entity.addPart(STRING_PART_NAME, new StringBody(mStringPart));
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            VolleyLog.e("UnsupportedEncodingException");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType()
    {
        return entity.getContentType().getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try
        {
            entity.writeTo(bos);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
        }
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
    {
        return Response.success("Uploaded", getCacheEntry());
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(String response)
    {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

It's pretty raw but I tried it with an image and a simple string and it works. The response is a placeholder, doesn't make much sense to return a Response String in this case. I had problems using apache httpmime to use MultipartEntity so I used this https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/ don't know if there's a better way.
Hope it helps.

**Edit**

You can use httpmime without using httpclientandroidlib, the only dependency is httpcore.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I'll test your solution tomorrow and accept it as the correct answer once I can verify it.

Comment: How can we implement progress bar for this multipart file upload? this supports for larger files? say 100mb!

Comment: @LOG_TAG: This won't support big files. Nor will it support a progress bar. Reason is that it will put all the data in a single byte[]. For big files, you want to use a InputStream, which does not seem possible with volley. But they (volley devs) as well say that volley is not made for big files.

Comment: @alex can you put some code how to use MultipartRequest?

Comment: I had to do some minor tweaking to get this to work for what I needed but the overall idea worked 100%. I was about to tear into the HurlStack so I am really glad I found this beforehand. Thanks!

Comment: I get this error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType

Comment: MultipartEntity using apache http. i want to do it without apache multipart library. how can i do this.

Comment: return entity.getContentType().getValue(); Error

Comment: MultipartEntity is detracted

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned in the presentation at the I/O (about 4:05), Volley "is terrible" for large payloads. As I understand it that means not to use Volley for receiving/sending (big) files. Looking at the code it seems that it is not even designed to handle multipart form data (e.g. Request.java has getBodyContentType() with hardcoded "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; HttpClientStack::createHttpRequest() can handle only byte[], etc...). Probably you will be able to create implementation that can handle multipart but If I were you I will just use HttpClient directly with MultipartEntity like:

```
    HttpPost req = new HttpPost(composeTargetUrl());
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
    entity.addPart(POST_IMAGE_VAR_NAME, new FileBody(toUpload));
    try {
        entity.addPart(POST_SESSION_VAR_NAME, new StringBody(uploadSessionId));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    req.setEntity(entity);
```

You may need [newer HttpClient](http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/using-newer-version-of-httpclient-like-4-1-x/) (i.e. not the built-in) or even better, [use Volley with newer HttpClient](http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/using-volley-android-with-external-httpclient-4-2-x/)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, your blog shows me something I wouldn't have though of. I will try your suggestion via the link above if I can't get Alex's solution to work. Cheers!

Comment: Hello @Ogre_BGR, Could you please provide a  full sample how to upload an image using you snap code. I tried many sample only, but their are very old and I cant get it to work. Thank you

Comment: Multipart is now supported. Look at the other answers on this page.

Comment: @MartinKonecny please link the correct answer in your comment so other users can go directly to it

Comment: How could I able to add other parameters along with multipart format in a single request?

Comment: @casillas `entity.addPart(YOUR_OTHER_VAR_NAME, new StringBody("string representation of your value"));`

Comment: Thanks friends, Can you please suggest ..what corrections I have to do for use Request.Method.PUT for the upload file image

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE 2015/08/26:**

If you don't want to use deprecated HttpEntity, here is my working sample code  (tested with ASP.Net WebAPI)

**MultipartActivity.java**

```
package com.example.volleyapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.example.volleyapp.BaseVolleyRequest;
import com.example.volleyapp.VolleySingleton;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MultipartActivity extends Activity {

    final Context mContext = this;
    String mimeType;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String boundary = "apiclient-" + System.currentTimeMillis();
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_multipart);             

        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_action_file_attachment_light);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        final byte[] bitmapData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        String url = "http://192.168.1.100/api/postfile";

        mimeType = "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary;

        BaseVolleyRequest baseVolleyRequest = new BaseVolleyRequest(1, url, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return mimeType;
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
                try {
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                            + "ic_action_file_attachment_light.png" + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    ByteArrayInputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapData);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // read file and write it into form...
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0) {
                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }

                    // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                    return bos.toByteArray();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return bitmapData;
            }
        };

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(mContext).addToRequestQueue(baseVolleyRequest);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_multipart, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**BaseVolleyRequest.java:**

```
package com.example.volleyapp;

import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;


public class BaseVolleyRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {

    private final Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;
    private final Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;

    public BaseVolleyRequest(String url, Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(0, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    }

    public BaseVolleyRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            return Response.success(
                    response,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
        return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
    }
}
```

**END OF UPDATE**

This is my working sample code (only tested with small-size files):

```
public class FileUploadActivity extends Activity {

    private final Context mContext = this;
    HttpEntity httpEntity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_upload);   

        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_home);
        if (drawable != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            final byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
            String url = "http://10.0.2.2/api/fileupload";
            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            // Add binary body
            if (bitmapdata != null) {
                ContentType contentType = ContentType.create("image/png");
                String fileName = "ic_action_home.png";
                builder.addBinaryBody("file", bitmapdata, contentType, fileName);
                httpEntity = builder.build();

                MyRequest myRequest = new MyRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                        try {                            
                            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, jsonString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                        
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    public String getBodyContentType() {
                        return httpEntity.getContentType().getValue();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        try {
                            httpEntity.writeTo(bos);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
                        }
                        return bos.toByteArray();
                    }
                };

                MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(myRequest);
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}

public class MyRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse>
```

Comment: Some servers are VERY picky. If you have issues add a SPACE between ";" and "filename=" when building Content-Disposition and "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Kevin. Actually, I have not had many server apps to check that :-)

Comment: @HemsLodha: pls take a look at RacZo's answer at my following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240177/working-post-multipart-request-with-volley-and-without-httpentity to see if it can help you or not :)

Comment: I'm sending post multipart request with volley and finally set parameter to url and it works. Thanks for help @BNK.

Comment: @user3561494 it´s not recommended for large-size files such as video

Answer (score 9):

> Complete Multipart Request with Upload Progress

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilterOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.util.CharsetUtils;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.beusoft.app.AppContext;

public class MultipartRequest extends Request<String> {

    MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    HttpEntity httpentity;
    private String FILE_PART_NAME = "files";

    private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
    private final File mFilePart;
    private final Map<String, String> mStringPart;
    private Map<String, String> headerParams;
    private final MultipartProgressListener multipartProgressListener;
    private long fileLength = 0L;

    public MultipartRequest(String url, Response.ErrorListener errorListener,
            Response.Listener<String> listener, File file, long fileLength,
            Map<String, String> mStringPart,
            final Map<String, String> headerParams, String partName,
            MultipartProgressListener progLitener) {
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mFilePart = file;
        this.fileLength = fileLength;
        this.mStringPart = mStringPart;
        this.headerParams = headerParams;
        this.FILE_PART_NAME = partName;
        this.multipartProgressListener = progLitener;

        entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        try {
            entity.setCharset(CharsetUtils.get("UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        buildMultipartEntity();
        httpentity = entity.build();
    }

    // public void addStringBody(String param, String value) {
    // if (mStringPart != null) {
    // mStringPart.put(param, value);
    // }
    // }

    private void buildMultipartEntity() {
        entity.addPart(FILE_PART_NAME, new FileBody(mFilePart, ContentType.create("image/gif"), mFilePart.getName()));
        if (mStringPart != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mStringPart.entrySet()) {
                entity.addTextBody(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return httpentity.getContentType().getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            httpentity.writeTo(new CountingOutputStream(bos, fileLength,
                    multipartProgressListener));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
        }
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

        try {
//          System.out.println("Network Response "+ new String(response.data, "UTF-8"));
            return Response.success(new String(response.data, "UTF-8"),
                    getCacheEntry());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // fuck it, it should never happen though
            return Response.success(new String(response.data), getCacheEntry());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

//Override getHeaders() if you want to put anything in header

    public static interface MultipartProgressListener {
        void transferred(long transfered, int progress);
    }

    public static class CountingOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {
        private final MultipartProgressListener progListener;
        private long transferred;
        private long fileLength;

        public CountingOutputStream(final OutputStream out, long fileLength,
                final MultipartProgressListener listener) {
            super(out);
            this.fileLength = fileLength;
            this.progListener = listener;
            this.transferred = 0;
        }

        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            out.write(b, off, len);
            if (progListener != null) {
                this.transferred += len;
                int prog = (int) (transferred * 100 / fileLength);
                this.progListener.transferred(this.transferred, prog);
            }
        }

        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            out.write(b);
            if (progListener != null) {
                this.transferred++;
                int prog = (int) (transferred * 100 / fileLength);
                this.progListener.transferred(this.transferred, prog);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Sample Usage**

```
protected <T> void uploadFile(final String tag, final String url,
            final File file, final String partName,         
            final Map<String, String> headerParams,
            final Response.Listener<String> resultDelivery,
            final Response.ErrorListener errorListener,
            MultipartProgressListener progListener) {
        AZNetworkRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new AZNetworkRetryPolicy();

        MultipartRequest mr = new MultipartRequest(url, errorListener,
                resultDelivery, file, file.length(), null, headerParams,
                partName, progListener);

        mr.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        mr.setTag(tag);

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(mr);

    }
```

Comment: Hi @AZ_ - i tried your code: But I get this error: MultipartRequest.getBody: IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream. Can you help please

Comment: I don't have your code, I cannot suggest anything better to open another question, most probable reason could be that you ran out of virtual memory.

Comment: I have Open I new Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474585/volley-multipartrequest-getbody-ioexception-writing-to-bytearrayoutputstream Can you help pls. thank you

Comment: How could I able to add other parameters along with multipart format in a single request?

Comment: @casillas add key value pair to header of the request.

Comment: Is there a way to cancel an ongoing request like this? Please refer to my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577601/how-do-you-cancel-a-volley-request-that-has-already-started

Comment: @AZ_ Can you give a real example? That is just a wrapper for the constructor. I would need how to add the file as a param like: `<input name="fileupload" type="file>`

Comment: see private String FILE_PART_NAME = "files"; in MultiPartRequest you can change it with your requirement.

Answer (score 8):

A very simple approach for the dev who just want to send POST parameters in multipart request.

> Make the following changes in class which extends Request.java

First define these constants :

```
String BOUNDARY = "s2retfgsGSRFsERFGHfgdfgw734yhFHW567TYHSrf4yarg"; //This the boundary which is used by the server to split the post parameters.
String MULTIPART_FORMDATA = "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + BOUNDARY;
```

Add a helper function to create a post body for you :

```
private String createPostBody(Map<String, String> params) {
        StringBuilder sbPost = new StringBuilder();
        if (params != null) {
            for (String key : params.keySet()) {
                if (params.get(key) != null) {
                    sbPost.append("\r\n" + "--" + BOUNDARY + "\r\n");
                    sbPost.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + key + "\"" + "\r\n\r\n");
                    sbPost.append(params.get(key).toString());
                }
            }
        }
        return sbPost.toString();
    }
```

Override getBody() and getBodyContentType

```
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return MULTIPART_FORMDATA;
}

public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        return createPostBody(getParams()).getBytes();
}
```

Comment: Very simply and works perfectly! I had to `sbPost.append("--" + BOUNDARY + "--");` right before I return since the API I'm using requires a closing tag

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me on the front-end but back-end specifically nodejs is having trouble parsing it? Did you experience any of that?

Comment: Sorry I don't have backend experience :(

Comment: @Arpit thanks, I was able to solve my issue by using this helper class instead https://gist.github.com/anggadarkprince/a7c536da091f4b26bb4abf2f92926594#file-volleymultipartrequest-java

Comment: Simple and useful. Thanks for sharing this approach!

Answer (score 4):

First answer on SO.

I have encountered the same problem and found @alex 's code very helpful. I have made some simple modifications in order to pass in as many parameters as needed through HashMap, and have basically copied `parseNetworkResponse()` from StringRequest. I have searched online and so surprised to find out that such a common task is so rarely answered. Anyway, I wish the code could help:

```
public class MultipartRequest extends Request<String> {

private MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

private static final String FILE_PART_NAME = "image";

private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
private final File file;
private final HashMap<String, String> params;

public MultipartRequest(String url, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, File file, HashMap<String, String> params)
{
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

    mListener = listener;
    this.file = file;
    this.params = params;
    buildMultipartEntity();
}

private void buildMultipartEntity()
{
    entity.addPart(FILE_PART_NAME, new FileBody(file));
    try
    {
        for ( String key : params.keySet() ) {
            entity.addPart(key, new StringBody(params.get(key)));
        }
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        VolleyLog.e("UnsupportedEncodingException");
    }
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType()
{
    return entity.getContentType().getValue();
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try
    {
        entity.writeTo(bos);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}

/**
 * copied from Android StringRequest class
 */
@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    String parsed;
    try {
        parsed = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        parsed = new String(response.data);
    }
    return Response.success(parsed, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(String response)
{
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}
```

And you may use the class as following:

```
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    params.put("type", "Some Param");
    params.put("location", "Some Param");
    params.put("contact",  "Some Param");


    MultipartRequest mr = new MultipartRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>(){

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("response", response);
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Volley Request Error", error.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    }, f, params);

    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(mr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, very light with high performance with payload large:

Android Asynchronous Http Client library: 
http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

```
private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

private void uploadFileExecute(File file) {

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

    try { params.put("photo", file); } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}

    client.post(getUrl(), params,

        new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            public void onSuccess(String result) {

                Log.d(TAG,"uploadFile response: "+result);

            };

            public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, String errorMsg) {

                Log.d(TAG,"uploadFile ERROR!");

            };

        }

    );

}
```

Comment: large file sizes give out of memory exception

Comment: @Ravi +1 this library sucks for uploading large files

Comment: if you wanna send large files use apache mime libraries for multipart and then post it using this library.

Comment: You need to compress the size of image and then use this library in order to upload image

I found solution from below URL:

http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-upload-image-to-java-server/

I hope this can save time of someone.

Comment: @Ravi apache mime will give you conflict and duplicate class error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Simple Solution And Complete Example for Uploading File Using Volley Android

1) Gradle Import

```
compile 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'
```

2)Now Create a Class RequestManager

```
public class RequestManager {
    private static RequestManager mRequestManager;
    /**
     * Queue which Manages the Network Requests :-)
     */
    private static RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    // ImageLoader Instance

    private RequestManager() {

    }

    public static RequestManager get(Context context) {

        if (mRequestManager == null)
            mRequestManager = new RequestManager();

        return mRequestManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param context application context
     */
    public static RequestQueue getnstance(Context context) {

        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        }

        return mRequestQueue;

    }


}
```

3)Now Create a Class to handle Request for uploading File WebService

```
public class WebService {
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static WebService apiRequests = null;

    public static WebService getInstance() {
        if (apiRequests == null) {
            apiRequests = new WebService();
            return apiRequests;
        }
        return apiRequests;
    }
    public void updateProfile(Context context, String doc_name, String doc_type, String appliance_id, File file, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        SimpleMultiPartRequest request = new SimpleMultiPartRequest(Request.Method.POST, "YOUR URL HERE", listener, errorListener);
//        request.setParams(data);
        mRequestQueue = RequestManager.getnstance(context);
        request.addMultipartParam("token", "text", "tdfysghfhsdfh");
        request.addMultipartParam("parameter_1", "text", doc_name);
        request.addMultipartParam("dparameter_2", "text", doc_type);
        request.addMultipartParam("parameter_3", "text", appliance_id);
            request.addFile("document_file", file.getPath());

        request.setFixedStreamingMode(true);
        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

4) And Now Call The method Like This to Hit the service

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements Response.ErrorListener, Response.Listener<String>{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                uploadData();
            }
        });
    }

    private void uploadData() {
        WebService.getInstance().updateProfile(getActivity(), "appl_doc", "appliance", "1", mChoosenFile, this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
     //Your response here 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error with your solution :                                                                       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(ILjava/lang/String;Lcom/android/volley/Request$Priority;Lcom/android/volley/Response$ErrorListener;Lcom/android/volley/RetryPolicy;)V in class Lcom/android/volley/Request; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.android.volley.Request' appears in /data/data/com.footballscout.app/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex)

Comment: did you check for the correct gradle and imports in the classes?

Comment: I used the once described here and your answer https://github.com/DWorkS/VolleyPlus

Comment: and check your imports in the class where ever u are using because you must not be using the correct imports for volley like the error is pointing on the error listener, check imports again and gradle then clean the project, thanks , if u still find any problem do let me know

Answer (score -2):

This is my way of doing it. It may be useful to others :

```
private void updateType(){
    // Log.i(TAG,"updateType");
     StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

         @Override
         public void onResponse(String response) {
             // running on main thread-------
             try {
                 JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response);
                 res.getString("result");
                 System.out.println("Response:" + res.getString("result"));

                 }else{
                     CustomTast ct=new CustomTast(context);
                     ct.showCustomAlert("Network/Server Disconnected",R.drawable.disconnect);
                 }

             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();

                 //Log.e("Response", "==> " + e.getMessage());
             }
         }
     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
             // running on main thread-------
             VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + volleyError.getMessage());

         }
     }) {
         protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
             HashMap<String, String> hashMapParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
             hashMapParams.put("key", "value");
             hashMapParams.put("key", "value");
             hashMapParams.put("key", "value"));
             hashMapParams.put("key", "value");
             System.out.println("Hashmap:" + hashMapParams);
             return hashMapParams;
         }
     };
     AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);

 }
```