# android volley posting binary body

Tags: http, post, binary, android-volley

Scenario - upload binary data in the body of a post, handle a response body containing JSON.

How to do the following using Volley?

```
 curl -X  POST  -H "X-Application-Id: 3KxPB" -H "X-REST-API-Key: jkuI9"  -H "Content-Type: audio/3gp"  --data-binary '@test.3gp' https://host/1/files/audio
```

IMO - there is a gap in Volley handling binary POST body types that apache httpclient handles in subclasses of [abstracthttpentity](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/index.html). If buffered binary data generated on the phone by camera, microphone, or other binary output sensors needs a mechanism to be wrapped and written to the body of a POST how to do it in volley?

I've looked at [PoolingByteArrayOutputStream](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/9e5c44f22b47fcb0d37c7b10de3b5db542424fa5/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/PoolingByteArrayOutputStream.java) and would like to do something like fill the buffer and get the PBAOutStrm ,writing to PBAOutStrm from the buffer and then flipping OutStrm to InputStream and then wrap it in the body of a POST request as something like a ByteArrayEntity.  I cant see how to do that in volley.

Comment: Robert, did you ever get an answer to this? I'm trying to do the same thing (accomplish the --data-binary parameter) and the answer below doesn't help.

Comment: did not end up using volley for this type of POST. other clients-http-libs do the job.

Answer (score 0):

To send binary data you can do something like what I did in this answer [How to send a “multipart/form-data” POST in Android with Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797468/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-post-in-android-with-volley/16803473#16803473) .

Comment: thanks. my app knows the file(s) buffers to be Posted. Not really any need for MMP form that better fits scenario with user selection of entities to post.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using a Volley GsonRequest:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    String url = "https://arcane-anchorage-34204.herokuapp.com/handleCode";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        JSONObject jsonBody = null;
        try {
            jsonBody = new JSONObject ("{\"code\":\"NZ4UBUB\"}");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error e = " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        GsonRequest<Routine[]> gsonRequest = new GsonRequest<Routine[]>(Request.Method.POST, url, Routine[].class, headers, new Response.Listener<Routine[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Routine[] routineData) {
                TextView serverData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.serverData);

                String complete = "";
                String repeat = "";
                String hold = "";
                String perform = "";
                String txtData = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < routineData.length; i++) {
                    complete = (routineData[i].instructions.complete != null) ? "Complete: " + routineData[i].instructions.complete : "";
                    repeat = (routineData[i].instructions.repeat != null) ? "Repeat: " + routineData[i].instructions.repeat : "";
                    hold = (routineData[i].instructions.hold != null) ? "Hold: " + routineData[i].instructions.hold : "";
                    perform = (routineData[i].instructions.perform != null) ? "Perform: " + routineData[i].instructions.perform : "";

                    txtData += "DESCRIPTION: " + routineData[i].description[0] + ": " + routineData[i].description[1] + ", " + complete  + ", " + repeat  + ", " + hold  + ", " + perform + " ";
                }
                serverData.setText("Response: " + txtData);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                TextView serverData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.serverData);

                serverData.setText("Response: " + volleyError.toString());

            }
        }, jsonBody);
        queue.add(gsonRequest);
    }
    public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {
        private final Gson gson = new Gson();
        private final Class<T> clazz;
        private final Map<String, String> headers;
        private final Response.Listener<T> listener;
        private JSONObject parameters = null;

        /**
         * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
         *
         * @param url URL of the request to make
         * @param clazz Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
         * @param headers Map of request headers
         */
        public GsonRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers,
                           Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
            super(method, url, errorListener);
            this.clazz = clazz;
            this.headers = headers;
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        public GsonRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers,
                           Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, JSONObject parameters) {
            this(method, url, clazz, headers, listener, errorListener);
            this.parameters = parameters;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            try {
                return parameters.toString().getBytes(getParamsEncoding());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
            listener.onResponse(response);
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            try {
                String json = new String(
                        response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                Log.i("RESPONSE", json);
                return Response.success(
                        gson.fromJson(json, clazz), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            }
        }
      }
    }
```