# How to multipart data using Android Volley

Tags: android, performance, android-volley

I am using Volley for calling web request for my app. But as i am Volley for first time. I just want to know that how to upload image/video media data via volley using multipart.

I searched for it many sites, I got some results over

[How to send a “multipart/form-data” POST in Android with Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797468/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-post-in-android-with-volley)

But, these methods does'nt look good or efficients. So, Please help me that how to upload media data using volley. Or i should not use Volley, and should go for the previous manual approach

Anyway, all thoughts and answers are extremely appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Uploading with progress  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28144660/185022

Answer (score 30):

Don't know if you have got an answer, but if you haven't try this:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;

public class MultipartRequest extends Request<String> {

// private MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
HttpEntity httpentity;
private static final String FILE_PART_NAME = "file";

private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
private final File mFilePart;
private final Map<String, String> mStringPart;

public MultipartRequest(String url, Response.ErrorListener errorListener,
        Response.Listener<String> listener, File file,
        Map<String, String> mStringPart) {
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

    mListener = listener;
    mFilePart = file;
    this.mStringPart = mStringPart;
    entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    buildMultipartEntity();
}

public void addStringBody(String param, String value) {
    mStringPart.put(param, value);
}

private void buildMultipartEntity() {
    entity.addPart(FILE_PART_NAME, new FileBody(mFilePart));
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mStringPart.entrySet()) {
        entity.addTextBody(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return httpentity.getContentType().getValue();
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        httpentity = entity.build();
        httpentity.writeTo(bos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}

@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    return Response.success("Uploaded", getCacheEntry());
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}
   }
```

In order to make it work you must use this java httpclients:
http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi
By the time I'm writing this answer (02/07/14) the version I'm using is 4.3.2.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Yes, it does. Give it a try !

Comment: Works like a charm, this answer should be accepted!

Comment: I have a problem with add library for my Android project. Please help. I'm using eclipse IDE.

Comment: Try asking a new question here on SO describing your problem, what have you tried.

Comment: @maohieng You should look at beginning the migration to Android Studio. [Google won't be supporting it much longer](http://www.droid-life.com/2015/06/26/google-to-stop-adt-eclipse-development/).

Comment: Uses HttpClient library which is now deprecated on Android. Have a look at https://www.maxester.com/blog/2019/10/04/upload-file-image-to-the-server-using-volley-in-android/ for a solution that doesn't depent on HttpClient

Answer (score 14):

You have to use the code below to upload image using multipart with volley. It works like a charm in my app.

```
public class MultipartRequest extends Request<String> {

    private MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

    private static final String FILE_PART_NAME = "file";
    private static final String STRING_PART_NAME = "text";

    private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
    private final File mFilePart;
    private final String mStringPart;

    public MultipartRequest(String url, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, Response.Listener<String> listener, File file, String stringPart)
    {
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

        mListener = listener;
        mFilePart = file;
        mStringPart = stringPart;
        buildMultipartEntity();
    }

    private void buildMultipartEntity()
    {
        entity.addPart(FILE_PART_NAME, new FileBody(mFilePart));
        try
        {
            entity.addPart(STRING_PART_NAME, new StringBody(mStringPart));
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            VolleyLog.e("UnsupportedEncodingException");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType()
    {
        return entity.getContentType().getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try
        {
            entity.writeTo(bos);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
        }
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
    {
        return Response.success("Uploaded", getCacheEntry());
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(String response)
    {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Uses deprecated `MultipartEntity`