# How would do I upload a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, file-upload, bitmap, base64, image-upload

I am currently making an app for students where they can upload a PDF file to a server. I am using the android Volley API but have been testing the function using JPEG files.

This is my code

```
  public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

How would I change this code so that a PDF can be uploaded instead?

Do I still used Base64? and imageBytes?

Or is there an alternate method?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reuse most of the code that you have there, instead of taking in a Bitmap, you would take in a File. You won't be able to use Bitmap.Compress on it though so that will need to be removed.

For uploading a PDF, you can Base64 encode it and send it as a string as part of the request, this might get out of control if you are handling large files.

The other option is to use a multipart form, I would suggest taking a look at this [stackoverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30530451/924) for how to do that.