# Send image via JsonObjectRequest Volley in Android?

Tags: android, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I have a POST method send a JsonObject via Volley:

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, postBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {                
             log("success");
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            log("" + error);
        }
    });
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
```

With postBody:

```
JSONObject postBody = new JSONObject();
    try {
        postBody.put("name", "rome");
        //postBody.put("image", file?);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        log("" + e);
    }
```

I want to send a image file with key "image" above. This file type is the same with file of form-data in [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/) (not url of file).

Is there anyway to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Try with  : "Bundle " or  https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-upload-image-to-server/

Comment: It is send url, not the file :(

Comment: How to use Bundle for above code?

Comment: You have to make a multi part request. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21635786/1320616

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload an image using Google Volley](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430599/upload-an-image-using-google-volley)

Comment: I'm still trying test it.