# send multipart images with volley and horizontal progress bar

Tags: android, file-upload, android-progressbar, multipart, android-volley

I want to upload images via volley using multipart and also want to show progress dialog during image upload.

I am use [this code for show progress dialog](http://toolongdidntread.com/android/android-multipart-post-with-progress-bar/) when images are upload and also [check this code for this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797468/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-post-in-android-with-volley)

and use below code for upload.

```
public void doFileUpload(ArrayList<MyUploadImage> images){
        try {
            //MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            //entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
            jo.put("NoOfImages", images.size());

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(link);

            CustomMultiPartEntity multipartContent = new CustomMultiPartEntity(new ProgressListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void transferred(long num)
                {
                    pd.setProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                }
            });

            //MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            int size = images.size();
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(images.get(i).getImageFile());

                multipartContent.addPart(("uploaded_file"+i), bin1);
            }

            multipartContent.addPart("girish", new StringBody(jo.toString()));
            totalSize = multipartContent.getContentLength();

            post.setEntity(multipartContent);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

            final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

            Log.e("Response", response_str);

            pd.dismiss();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            pd.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            pd.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Volley doesnt provide support for Multipart. But you can still use volley's framework and provide you
own implementation of HttpStack just like we used for SSL connections.

```
public class MultiPartRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONObject> {

    /* To hold the parameter name and the File to upload */
    private Map<String,File> fileUploads = new HashMap<String,File>();

    /* To hold the parameter name and the string content to upload */
    private Map<String,String> stringUploads = new HashMap<String,String>();

    public void addFileUpload(String param,File file) {
        fileUploads.put(param,file);
    }

    public void addStringUpload(String param,String content) {
        stringUploads.put(param,content);
    }

    public Map<String,File> getFileUploads() {
        return fileUploads;
    }

    public Map<String,String> getStringUploads() {
        return stringUploads;
    }
}
```

And in your HttpStack implementation, create MultiPartEntity and set it to HttpRequest. Refer SslHttpStack createHttpRequest method for more details.

```
private static void setMultiPartBody(HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase httpRequest, Request<?> request) throws AuthFailureError {

    // Return if Request is not MultiPartRequest
    if(request instanceof MultiPartRequest == false) {
        return;
    }

    MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);  
    //Iterate the fileUploads
    Map<String,File> fileUpload = ((MultiPartRequest)request).getFileUploads();

    for (Map.Entry<String, File> entry : fileUpload.entrySet()) {
        multipartEntity.addPart(((String)entry.getKey()), new FileBody((File)entry.getValue()));
    }

    //Iterate the stringUploads
    Map<String,String> stringUpload = ((MultiPartRequest)request).getStringUploads();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : stringUpload.entrySet()) {
        try {
            multipartEntity.addPart(((String)entry.getKey()), new StringBody((String)entry.getValue()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    httpRequest.setEntity(multipartEntity);
}
```

See this soluction here : https://github.com/smanikandan14/Volley-demo