# how to display multiple images with volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I couldn't find any helpful answers on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=volley+display+multiple+image) or google about displaying multiple images using Volley.

this is my code in displaying one image:

mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.zproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private NetworkImageView mNetworkImageView;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        mImageLoader = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
                .getImageLoader();
        //Image URL - This can point to any image file supported by Android
        final String url = "http://goo.gl/0rkaBz";
        mImageLoader.get(url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(mNetworkImageView,
                R.drawable.add, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
        mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(url, mImageLoader);
    }
}
```

the volley skeleton

```
package com.example.zproject;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.LruCache;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Network;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;

/**
 * Custom implementation of Volley Request Queue
 */
public class CustomVolleyRequestQueue {

    private static CustomVolleyRequestQueue mInstance;
    private static Context mCtx;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;


    private CustomVolleyRequestQueue(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequestQueue getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new CustomVolleyRequestQueue(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(mCtx.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
            mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
            // Don't forget to start the volley request queue
            mRequestQueue.start();
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return mImageLoader;
    }

}
```

I had problem in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112694/how-to-do-upload-image-with-volley-library) because importing

```
import com.android.volley.toolbox.MultipartRequest;
import com.android.volley.examples.toolbox.MyVolley;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to download images separetly, making separate request for each one.

You may find [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library very handy for image downloading and displaying

If you decide to use `Volley` - there's also no problem to display several images at the same time.

If you have [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) or some other view with a set of similar data then you have to use Adapter. Read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) as an example. However you don't need this if you just have several `ImageView`  views on your `layout`.