# Upload file Android without httpclient

Tags: android, file-upload, httpclient, android-volley, multipartform-data

I'm looking for a solution for uploading file to my sv. I found some posts using Volley and HttpClient to send “multipart/form-data” POST in Android such as: 
[How to send a “multipart/form-data” POST in Android with Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797468/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-post-in-android-with-volley)
or https://gist.github.com/AizazAZ/55c316152ecace931bc0 
But they use HttpClient and HttpEntity and they are deprecated in API level 22. So, what is the replacement for that? Please give me some advices. Thank you for your help!