# Android Volley Library: How to send an image to server?

Tags: android, jpeg, android-volley, android-networking

Hy guys!

I have a `jpg image stored on my device` and I want to `sent it to server`(mywebsite.com/api.php). I would like to use `volley library` because it is made by official android developers from google and I think they will add it to the sdk as soon as possible.

Right now I am using the folowing code to send Strings to the server:

```
 postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        // code here for response
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // code here for error response
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            // the POST parameters:
            params.put("key", "myApiKey");
            params.put("data","stringOfMyData");
            return params;
        }
    };
```

How could I send the jpg to server with volley library? Every time I send something I need to send it together with the API key in order to receive information to server, so I cant change `Map<String, String>` to `Map<String, File>` because my API key is a string.

I have read that there is a solution to change my image to a `byte[] array` and then converting it to a `base64 string` format, but I would want to avoid this if possible.

Is there any other solution to send the image without converting it to a `base64 string`?

Any reference or advice is welcome! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files are sent using `multipart` support in `POST` request. It is same as in HTML forms as here.

`Volley` doesn't have multipart support by default but it's flexible so you can extend its `Request` class to implement your own version of `multipart`.

You can find one implementation of `MultipartRequest` class from this gist and just use in your program
https://gist.github.com/ishitcno1/11394069

You can consume this class something like this:

```
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String url = "YOUR POST URL";
    String image_path = "your local image path";

    params.put("your_extra_params", "value");

    MultipartRequest multipartRequest =

            new MultipartRequest(url, params, image_path, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Success Response: " + response.toString());

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    if (error.networkResponse != null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error Response code: " +
                                error.networkResponse.statusCode);


                        try {



                    }


                    if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    }
                }
            });

    requestQueue.add(multipartRequest);
```

Comment: I dont fully undertand the constructors from the github example . And the parameters `new MultipartRequest(url, params, image_path,...` doesnt match the MultipartRequest constructors paramenters. Because of that I get the following error and possible solution: Cannot Resolve Constructor...Change signature of MultipartRequest

Comment: I think the correct order of parameters is: `multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(url, imagePath, params, ...)` because the constructor parameters order is  `public MultipartRequest(String url, String filePath, String routeId,...)` but I dont know what routeId is and how could I add a HashMap(`HashMap<String,String>` is not the same thing as `String`)

Comment: You can take a look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797468/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-post-in-android-with-volley/31718902#31718902). Two options: with or without HttpEntity :-)

Comment: What is MRouteId? And I get error: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
 at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.<init>(FileBody.java:89)"