# Android: What is the best HTTP library for files?

Tags: android, network-programming, android-volley, retrofit, loopj

Hy guys!

I am working on an android project(`java`) with another guy working on the `server-side(php)`. In my application I need to call `POST` and `GET` methods in order to `upload files to server, download files, send Strings, byte[] array etc`.

My question is: What is the best library to use in my case?(I think my files will not exceed `3mb`)

I am new in android so I tried so far:

**1.**`Android Asynchronous Http Client`(com.loopj.android:android-async-http:x.x.x)
-we gave up to this because it is not from a "trusted" source

**2.**`AsyncTask+HttpClient+HttpPost`
-we gave up to this too

**3.**`Volley library`
-best so far(for strings, image request), but it needs additional libraries to send images to server(`org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5`)
-I followed so examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797468/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-post-in-android-with-volley) but I got exceptions, error, libraries error(duplicates) and never managed to solve one without other showing up.
-so I gave up on this too

`My question posted for volley library` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700885/android-volley-library-how-to-send-an-image-to-server)

**4.** Now I am thinking about using `Retrofit`, but dont know it fits my needs:
-send strings and all types of primitive data
-send image/images to server(together with an `Api key`)
-download image/images from server

Tell me if I am wrong somewhere or if I missed something working with the libraries specified above. I managed to send simple data with all of these, but I didnt managed to send `Files`(excepting `loopj` library).

Do you think should I go back to `Volley`, or starting reading about `Retrofit`? `Volley` seems to be the most flexible one, but not for `uploading files`.

Any reference or advice is welcome! Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
I found a possible solution for my problem:
-I convert my file/image to a `byte array` and `encode` it to a `base64 string`
-I send the string to server as basic `StringRequest` with `HashMap<String,String>`(Using Volley library from Google developers)
-The server decode the string a save the file

Comment: Kindly upload your piece of code that u mentioned in update section Tanx in advance

Comment: @Adil You can check this question and follow the answer to encode and decode in Base64 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360403/base-64-encode-and-decode-example-code and this to send data with Volley http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194517/android-send-image-encoded-to-base64-using-volley

Comment: Tanx dear @Cristian.R

Answer (score 2):

I think a very good fit for you would be AndroidAsync.
You can find more about it on their GitHub repository here: https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync

As an example for you on how to upload files to server:

```
AsyncHttpPost post = new AsyncHttpPost("http://myservercom/postform.html");
MultipartFormDataBody body = new MultipartFormDataBody();
body.addFilePart("my-file", new File("/path/to/file.txt");
body.addStringPart("foo", "bar");
post.setBody(body);
AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance().execute(post, new StringCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, AsyncHttpResponse source, String result) {
        if (e != null) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Server says: " + result);
    }
});
```

There is also NanoHTTPD which you can find here: https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I didnt knew about those but I can't accept your answer as most helpful because those are not from a trusted source too(loops metioned in question is better than both). My project manager would never lets me to use something like that. I updated my question if you wanna see a posible/temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `HttpURLConnection` its really easy to send data to a server.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Comment: Instead of *you should try*, why don't you add a small example and provide that link for reference. That'd be really helpful!