# Android Send image encoded to Base64 using Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am letting the user select a image and then the image will be converted to Base64. I am trying to append the Base64 String to my url(**Json Format**) like in the below

```
http://codemoirai.esy.es/register.php?UserDetails={"Sex":"Male","Username":"joes","Bitmap":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAtAAAALQCAIAAAA2NdDLAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U\/gAAAgAEl......
```

But i am getting a error like this:

```
 BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 414 for http://codemoirai.esy.es/register.php?UserDetails={"Sex":"Male","Username":"joes","Bitmap":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAtAAAALQCAIAAAA2NdDLAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U\/gAA...........
```

Can i know what is causing this error? How can send a image file which is encoded to Base64 format using Volley?

ThankYou

Comment: Code 414 explain it all. The request string is too long and exceeds the limit.

Comment: In order to resolve this look for something like LimitRequestLine

Comment: Have a look at this thread: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response [code 414](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) is Request-URI Too Long (Your base64 image string is too long to put in url).

> The server is refusing to service the request because the Request-URI
>   is longer than the server is willing to interpret. This rare condition
>   is only likely to occur when a client has improperly converted a POST
>   request to a GET request with long query information, when the client
>   has descended into a URI "black hole" of redirection (e.g., a
>   redirected URI prefix that points to a suffix of itself), or when the
>   server is under attack by a client attempting to exploit security
>   holes present in some servers using fixed-length buffers for reading
>   or manipulating the Request-URI.

So you should change from http get to http post and send base64 image in http body

Your server must handle http post data. I dont know what language you use to implement your server side. So i only post client sample 
Sample

```
public void uploadAvatar(String username,String sex, String accessToken, String image, Response.Listener<JSONObject> success, Response.ErrorListener error) {
    String endpoint = "your server api url";
    ScoinJsonRequest request = new ScoinJsonRequest(Request.Method.POST, endpoint, getuploadAvatarParams(user, sex, image), success, error);
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(request);
}

private Map<String, String> getuploadAvatarParams(String username,String sex,String stringBase64) 
 {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
     params.put("username", username);
     params.put("gender", sex);
     params.put("ibase64", stringBase64);

    return params;
}
```

Then you can use uploadAvatar function and input all the required params.
About server side you can search read `http post data + your language`. I give you a link to [c# example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20151556/1050058)

Comment: I am new to volley! if you dont mind can you please elaborate  with your answer

Comment: Hey i am using php on my server side! $_Post["gender"] this is how weget the params right?

Comment: @Jois Yes. You can check answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8207498/1050058)