# Uploading files to server using Volley

Tags: android, file-upload, android-volley

I am new to Android and I need some help.
I want to upload files to server using Google Volley, I did a rough search about it but since I am new to android, I didn't find any clear answer.
I would really appreciate of anyone help me with it and explain how to do it with some details.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to send? Image files can be sent with Picasso. Volley isn't really equipped out of the box to handle multi-part requests, but you can do some work to make it happen.

Comment: I don't have any specific type of files, I mean the use can upload any types of files, can't I do that? Can you suggest any other solutions?

Comment: Yea you have to implement your own request for volley to allow for multi-part data posts. Read more into it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797468/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-post-in-android-with-volley Do note that, like was previously stated, volley is not really meant for large data loads.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll have a look at it. I hope it will work.