# How to send a multipart request in Android with Volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have some code to send multipart request with Android Volley. But When i'm try running the code, showing error "BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401".

Hope, anyone can help me. Thanks.

This My Multipartrequest.

```
public class MultipartRequest extends Request<String> {
  MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
  HttpEntity httpentity;
  private String FILE_PART_NAME = "upload";

  private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
  private final File mFilePart;
  private final Map<String, String> mStringPart;

public MultipartRequest(String url, Response.ErrorListener errorListener,
                        Response.Listener<String> listener, File file,
                        long length, Map<String, String> mStringPart, HashMap<String, String> headers, HashMap<String, String> params, Object o) {
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

    this.mListener = listener;
    this.mFilePart = file;
    this.mStringPart = mStringPart;

    entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    try {
        entity.setCharset(CharsetUtils.get("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    buildMultipartEntity();
    httpentity = entity.build();
}

private void buildMultipartEntity() {
    entity.addPart(FILE_PART_NAME, new FileBody(mFilePart, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), mFilePart.getName()));
    if (mStringPart != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mStringPart.entrySet()) {
            entity.addTextBody(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return httpentity.getContentType().getValue();
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try
    {
        httpentity.writeTo(bos);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}

@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

    try {
        System.out.println("Network Response "+ new String(response.data, "UTF-8"));
        return Response.success(new String(response.data, "UTF-8"),
                getCacheEntry());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.success(new String(response.data), getCacheEntry());
    }
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}
}
```

And i call multipart request like this.

```
 private void upload(){
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String credentials = AppConfig.USER_API+":"+AppConfig.PASSWORD_API;
    String auth = "Basic "
            + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(),
            Base64.NO_WRAP);
    headers.put("Authorization", auth);

    File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("desc", "OK");

    MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(AppConfig.URL_REPORT,

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed : " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            },
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }

            }, sourceFile, sourceFile.length(), null, headers, params, null);
    VolleyController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(multipartRequest);
}
```

Comment: I cannof find where did you process the headers inside MultipartRequest class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, I cannot find where did you process the headers inside MultipartRequest class

So update your class like this:

```
public class MultipartRequest extends Request<String>{

   ...
   private final Map<String, String> mHeaders;
   ...

    public MultipartRequest(..., Map<String, String> headers, ...) {
        super(...);
        ...
        this.mHeaders = headers;
        ...
    }

   @Override
   public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
       return (mHeaders != null) ? mHeaders : super.getHeaders();
   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: Glad it could help :-)

Comment: why i'm submit to uploaded data showing error 500 ?

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error can be because of many reasons, can you check / debug the server-side app? And how about in Sep 12, you said it worked for you?