# Can't upload file from android app to wep api

Tags: java, c#, android, file-upload, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to upload an image file from an android app using java to an aspnet webapi with no success.  I always get a response code of 500.  Below is the basic code for preparing the sending of data from my android app.  This code works when calling a php script but not when I call a web api controller shown below.

```
   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);

           url = new URL("http://www.myserver.com/webapi/api/fileupload/post/thisfile");
           connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs &amp; Outputs.
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            // Set HTTP method to POST.
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
            outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"" + sourceFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

Below is the basic web api controller code to do the file upload:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
 public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
            // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                //    return "Unsupported media type";
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }
            string root = "e:/web/myserver/htdocs/cemetery/pics/";
            var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

       return task;
    }
```

I changed the code above to send back a string and it says that my request does not contain multipart/form-data.  Below is my webapiconfig.cs file route for this controller.

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "FileUploadApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}", 
           defaults: new { action = "post", name = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
```

I appreciate any help in determining what is wrong with my code so I can upload a file from an android java app to a webapi controller.

Comment: what is the  connection.getResponseCode(); after opening the connection in first line?

Comment: The response code is 500 which doesn't tell you much.  It throws an exception on the first instruction in the web api program: throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

Comment: what is the file extension? Visit this article : http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

Comment: The file extension is .jpg.  The example you referenced uses a php script to upload the file.  I am already doing that with an existing php script.  I want to be able to do the same thing with a wep api.  There doesn't seem to be any examples out there for this scenario.

Comment: 'The response code is 500 which doesn't tell you much' ??? It's an http error code. What does it mean? You could have told that right away.

Comment: I compared my java code and the code in the above example and the only difference I see is the url.  The example references a php script while mine references a webapi controller.

Comment: I did say I received a 500 response code in my first paragraph.  What I meant is that a 500 response code does not give you a specific reason.  It means something is wrong but doesn't tell you what.

Comment: 'The example you referenced uses a php script to upload the file'. Don't think so. It will use a php script to receive the uploaded file.

Comment: Please tell what http error 500 stands for.

Comment: There is no specific error message for http error 500. It is a general error which you have to explore deeper on your own.

Comment: I understand that the example shows how to upload a file.  My problem is receiving the file in webapi controller.  I still don't see any difference in my java program and the example cited above.

Comment: 'There is no specific error message for http error 500. '. You are wrong. A little googling would tell you how it is named.

Comment: If you know so much why don't you tell me what the 500 error is?  You obviously aren't contributing anything to the solution.  I am closing this question since it seems to be attracting argumentative trolls.

Comment: You can read [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797468/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-post-in-android-with-volley/31718902#31718902)