# How to select any file from recent and upload it on server?

Tags: android, file-upload, server, image-upload, recent-file-list

i wanna upload files on server from android app. so User can pick any file from recent like image, doc or any PDF in android app and will upload on server.

So please tell me how to open that recent activity and select any file and how to upload it on server.

Please help me this very important for me.

Comment: http://osamashabrez.com/simple-client-server-communication-in-android/

Comment: whats your approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `*/*` for open all files as in android.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();    
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.perform_action_with)), attachmentChoice);
```

note:where `attachmentChoice` is **Constant**.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to upload file(Image,PDF,DOC file on server) . should i use multi-part or something else and how will i get to know which file user has selected?

Comment: dear after selecting any file ,in you onActivityResult() you can create path from URI. then you can get file type from there.
 public static String getFileType(String path) {
        String substring = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        return substring.substring(substring.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    }

Comment: which is the best way to upload file on server from app?

Comment: i think use multi-part-service.

Comment: can i upload doc , pdf or other text files using multi-part?

Comment: yes dear,see@http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797468/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-post-in-android-with-volley