# Upload video in Android with Volley

Tags: java, android, request, android-volley

I'm trying to upload video with Volley using a POST request but i don't know how create the stream of byte of a .mp4 video saved on my Android phone. Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not the good one, I'd say. It could work but there are much simpler ways: why don't use a File and upload it to your server as a multipart/form request for instance: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16803473/2545832) is really good in this way.

It could be that it's not gonna work with big files and you won't be able to add a progress bar with this option.

I'm a big fan of Volley but it is pretty obvious that it hasn't been design for heavy file transfers and is focused on consuming a simple REST/JSON API. Therefore, I would recommend to switch library to something designed for your needs like [this one (Android Async)](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync). It is, to me, much better **FOR THAT PURPOSE** (and if you need a webserver too!)

Hope it helps