# Volley MultipartRequest VS StringRequest with params

Tags: android, request, android-volley, multipartform-data

Well, that might be a simple question but, in my app I have to upload some data to a server, it will be some user images (3 or 4) together with some other user data (name, pass, age, etc..).

For that I will be using Volley, and from the answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797468/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-post-in-android-with-volley/16803473) I have been reading about using a `MultipartRequest`.

However, I am not sure about the difference, or the benefit of using a `MultipartRequest` if in the usual `StringRequest` I have the method `getParams` where I could do like that:

```
override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
       val params = HashMap<String, String>()
       params.put("image1", encodedImage1Base64)
       params.put("image2", encodedImage2Base64)
       params.put("image3", encodedImage3Base64)
       params.put("image4", encodedImage4Base64)
       params.put("user_name", userName)
       params.put("user_pass", userPass)
       params.put("user_age", userAge)
       params.put("user_email", userEmail)
       // and any other user data needed
       return params
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented both methods for uploading images with Volley, and MultipartRequest has worked better than Base64 encoded string. Base64 encoding increases data transferred by 33%. Multipart is usually the way to go when uploading binary data, specially if you want to upload huge files.

Comment: ok that is very interesting, but don't you have to use `Base64` encoding to upload images no matter which method you use??, how do you upload image directly without encoding?

Comment: No, Multipart Request doesn't use base64 encoding, it transfers the image bytes directly to the server. Check this example: [link]https://gist.github.com/anggadarkprince/a7c536da091f4b26bb4abf2f92926594