# How do I send a HTTP-Post Request with both Strings and Files in Volley (multipart-formdata)?

Tags: android, rest, post, android-volley, multipartform-data

So I have to do a Post-Request to a server. The content type of the request is `multipart/form-data`. The problem I am currently facing is the following. How do i I send both multiple files and String values in one request.

Where is what the request looks like in Postman : [image: Where is what the request looks like in Postman]

Comment: check this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797468/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-post-in-android-with-volley?answertab=votes#tab-top