# How to inject file contents into Gson serialisation?

Tags: java, android, serialization, gson

for an Android app I'm working on I'd like to be able to send a REST POST using Volley with a body byte stream which includes a number of photos on the device.

I'm using Gson to serialize a list of objects. in my Volley Request `getBody()` method e.g. something like:

```
final Set<MySession> sessions;
....
new Gson().toJson(sessions).getBytes();
```

where `MySession` looks a bit like:

```
public class MySession {
....
  private Set<MyDefect> defects;
....
}
public class MyDefect {
...
  private Set<String> photoPaths;
...
}
```

What I have works fine up to a point: the `REST` call is made and the sessions/defects are serialized pretty much exactly as I want. The only thing I'd like to change is that when the sessions/defects are serialized by Gson, that instead of serializing the photo paths, that the byte arrays for the corresponding images are serialized???

so, the JSON sent would be something like:

```
[{
....
  "defects":
    [ {
          .... 
          "photos": [ [byte-array-for-photo-1], [byte-array-for-photo-2].....],
           ....
       }
```

i.e. the "photoPath" bit has been replaced by "photos".

I know you can use Gson with custom Serializers so that the byte array of each image @ photoPath is read in and added as a property for serialization BUT I'd rather not have to load in large image byte arrays into memory. What I'd like to do is to somehow be able to 'inject' a byte object stream as part of the serialization?

I also know that you can use JsonWriters and Appenders with toJson: what I'm not sure about is whether it's possible to use these in combination with a custom serializer to do what I'm trying to do? (Or whether there's another approach I haven't realised?)

Any suggestions welcome!
Kind regards,
Mike Beale

Comment: btw, I'm assuming that a viable approach is something along the lines of encapsulating the photo paths into  'Photo' class objects and registering a customer serializer for the class which returns something like: JsonPrimitive(Base64.encodeToString(src, Base64.NO_WRAP));
where src is the byte[] for the contents of a photo file...

But as mentioned originally, I'd rather use something like a ByteArrayOutputStream rather than reading the whole file in, because of the image sizes...

Comment: I strongly advise against trying to transport binary data in textual format - to properly deserialize this you will need to encode your binary data as a string which increases its size extensively! Instead either do a multipart/form-data POST having the textual information as form-data or POST the metadata first and the images using a different representation afterwards.
Also, it might be nitpicky, but REST is a concept, not a technology. You do HTTP POSTs and only if your HTTP-based application adheres to a certain set of rules your API can be called RESTful.

Comment: Do you think a `ByteArrayOutputStream` is something like a live stream between client and server? If you want to send giant photos as text they need to be in your memory anyway! A HTTP POST is a single request from Java programming point of view.

Comment: Hi Smutje - thanks for the comments.No, didn't think that the BAOS was a 'live stream' but maybe my thought process was a little muddy!

Comment: Something we did in the past was a POST containing text and author to something like /api/posts returning the ID of the created entry and a list of (binary) POSTs to /api/posts/<ID>/images where each post contains the images data as binary body.

Comment: I'll take a look at the multi-part/form route: A brief search has come up with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797468/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-post-in-android-with-volley/16803473#16803473 which I'll digest.

Thanks for your input @Smutje.