# How would I implement using multipart form data?

Tags: java, android, api, multipart

I changed the `HttpPost` that I have for security.

I am able to get the app to  load/take picture, but it can't talk to the API, because the API is using a different retrieval method.

I do have an example of multipart coding but unsure how to implement with this.
An example of what I'm doing/what I need to do can be found [here](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/08/16/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-one-request-along-with-other-string-parameters-in-android/).

How would I implement using multipart form data?

```
 protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = ((Main) parentActivity).mPhoto;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // compress bitmap into the byte array output stream
    bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, baos);
    // form byte array out of byte array output stream
    byte[] ba = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
            "-----------------------------------");
    // Add your data


    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", encodedImage));
    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream inputstream = entity.getContent();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        results = sb.toString();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to start by converting using the multi-part method.

```
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = ((Main) parentActivity).mPhoto;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // compress bitmap into the byte array output stream
    bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, baos);
    // form byte array out of byte array output stream
    byte[] ba = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

By going to this, which is actually in stackoverflow, [Post multipart request with Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017414/post-multipart-request-with-android-sdk), provide key examples and samples of how multi-part works.

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("some url");

    MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);  
    multipartEntity.addPart("Title", new StringBody("Title"));
    multipartEntity.addPart("Nick", new StringBody("Nick"));
    multipartEntity.addPart("Email", new StringBody("Email"));
    multipartEntity.addPart("Description", new StringBody(Settings.SHARE.TEXT));
    multipartEntity.addPart("Image", new FileBody(image));
    httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);

    mHttpClient.execute(httppost, new PhotoUploadResponseHandler());
```