# upload multiple bit map image to php server

Tags: android

I want to convert bitmap arraylist to file .

```
                File file=new File(alist1.get(1));
                multipartEntity.addPart("image1", new FileBody(new File(alist1.get(1))));
                multipartEntity.addPart("image2",new FileBody(image));
                multipartEntity.addPart("image3", new FileBody(image));
                multipartEntity.addPart("image4", new FileBody(image));
                multipartEntity.addPart("image5", new FileBody(image));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Uploading Files Link](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/08/16/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-one-request-along-with-other-string-parameters-in-android/)

This is the best way you can do this even i have used this

If you don's have the JAR files get that from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017414/post-multipart-request-with-android-sdk)