# file upload using httppost android

Tags: android, file-upload

I have tried so many methods and answers that described on stack overflow and other blogs for uploading a file from my android app to my server but none of them worked for me.

I used httpclient4.3.3.jar,httpcore4.3.3.jar and httpmime4.3.3.jar

Am not getting any error messages and my app working fine. But not data coming in my server, am using php server and my server side code is bellow.

```
$file_path = "uploads/";

$file_path = $file_path.basename( $_FILES['file_data']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_data']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

please give me any working samples or code with required libs. So many days am working on it.. please help me with a complete answer.

Comment: Can you post the part where you `execute` the request?

Comment: try  http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106.Check its upload method.Might be helpfull

Comment: Try this method http://stackoverflow.com/a/5220954/403255

Comment: @ Rajesh , i have already posted my httprequest codes and used libs

Comment: Maybe you haven't *read* the comment. You're creating an `HttpClient`, but you also need to `execute` the request. I don't see this part in the code. Maybe this is the reason why it's not sending the data.

Comment: @Rajesh am using HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);    for execute post request, evey time am getting 400 bad request.

Comment: @Rajesh also MultipartEntity is deprecated so now am using  MultipartEntityBuilder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

```
 public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
      String fileName = sourceFileUri;

      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;  
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
      File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

      if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

           dialog.dismiss(); 

           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                               +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                           +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
               }
           }); 

           return 0;

      }
      else
      {
           try { 

                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file";filename=""
                                         + fileName + """ + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                          +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                          +uploadFileName;

                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });                
               }    

               //close the streams //
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              ex.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException", 
                                                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

              Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
          } catch (Exception e) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              e.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
              Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                               + e.getMessage(), e);  
          }
          dialog.dismiss();       
          return serverResponseCode; 

       } // End else block 
     }
```

**You need to add following Jar in Your project** , here i am giving you direct link for downloading.

1. [httpclient-4.2.2.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/httpclient/httpclient-4.2.2.jar.zip),
2. [httpmime-4.0.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/httpmime/httpmime-4.0.jar.zip)

Comment: i need httppost method for uploading file, can you give me any working code and proper libs

Comment: **This is working example for uploading file on server ,You just need modified these code according to your code** Download libs from here, [httpclient-4.2.2.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/httpclient/httpclient-4.2.2.jar.zip) and [httpmime-4.0.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/httpmime/httpmime-4.0.jar.zip).

Comment: thanks its works.. but i need httppost method file uploading.. do you have any idea.

Comment: THAT SAMPLE IS FILE UPLOADING METHOD