# Uploading file in php server from android device

Tags: php, android, file-upload

I am trying to upload file to a php server from my android device but  server is not receiving any file. here is my sample code, I found  it on-line.
php server , I am uploading a file through chunk

**My Android code**

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private TextView messageText;
private Button uploadButton, btnselectpic;
private ImageView imageview;
private int serverResponseCode = 0;
private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

private String upLoadServerUri = null;
private String imagepath=null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
    btnselectpic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
    imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);

    btnselectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    upLoadServerUri = "http://192.168.2.4/fileupload/UploadToServer.php";
}


@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if(arg0==btnselectpic)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
    }
    else if (arg0==uploadButton) {

         dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
         messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {

                  uploadFile(imagepath);

             }
           }).start();     
    }

} 

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath(); 

        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" +imagepath);

    }
}
     public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


      String fileName = sourceFileUri;

      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;  
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
      File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

      if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

           dialog.dismiss(); 

           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+imagepath);

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
               }
           }); 

           return 0;

      }
      else
      {
           try { 

                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("file", fileName); 

               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";file\""
                                         + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                  +" c:/xamp/htdocs/file upload/uploads";
                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });                
               }    

               //close the streams //
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              ex.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

              Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
          } catch (Exception e) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              e.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
              Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);  
          }
          dialog.dismiss();       
          return serverResponseCode; 

       } // End else block 
     }}
```

PHP Server code
in file uploading ,I am done file uploading done through chunk ,please anyone help me send right code file uploading through chunk  and relevant android file uploading code

```
<?php

if (empty($_FILES) || $_FILES['file']['error']) {
die('{"OK": 0, "info": "Failed to move uploaded file."}');
}

$chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;

$fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$filePath = "uploads/$fileName";


// Open temp file
$out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
//$out2 = @fopen("{$filePath}.part2", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
if ($out) {
// Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
$in = @fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

if ($in) {
while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
      fwrite($out, $buff);
   //print($out);
 // echo sizeof($out);
} else
die('{"OK": 0, "info": "Failed to open input stream."}');

@fclose($in);

@fclose($out);

@unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
} else
die('{"OK": 0, "info": "Failed to open output stream."}');


// Check if file has been uploaded

if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1)
{
// Strip the temp .part suffix off
rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
}


die('{"OK": 1, "info": "Upload successful."}');?>
```

Comment: You can upload file using FTP and with help of API (AsyncHttpResponseHandler)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138881/file-upload-using-httppost-android/22139271#22139271

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't know about your code but providing you both working codes:
This is for all types of files. I used it for image, audio and for video files.

Android:

```
new UploadFileAsync().execute("");



  private class UploadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
  String sourceFileUri = "/mnt/sdcard/abc.png";

            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

            if (sourceFile.isFile()) {

                try {
                    String upLoadServerUri = "http://website.com/abc.php?";

                    // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                            sourceFile);
                    URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE",
                            "multipart/form-data");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                            "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("bill", sourceFileUri);

                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"bill\";filename=\""
                            + sourceFileUri + "\"" + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    // create a buffer of maximum size
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // read file and write it into form...
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0) {

                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math
                                .min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,
                                bufferSize);

                    }

                    // send multipart form data necesssary after file
                    // data...
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                            + lineEnd);

                    // Responses from the server (code and message)
                    serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    String serverResponseMessage = conn
                            .getResponseMessage();

                    if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                        // messageText.setText(msg);
                        //Toast.makeText(ctx, "File Upload Complete.",
                        //      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // recursiveDelete(mDirectory1);

                    }

                    // close the streams //
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    // dialog.dismiss();
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                // dialog.dismiss();

            } // End else block


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // dialog.dismiss();

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

PHP::

```
 <?php


     if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['bill']['tmp_name'])) {
    $uploads_dir = './';
                            $tmp_name = $_FILES['bill']['tmp_name'];
                            $pic_name = $_FILES['bill']['name'];
                            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir.$pic_name);
                            }
               else{
                   echo "File not uploaded successfully.";
           }

   ?>
```

Comment: @Purushotamrawat no file size limit for uploading it depends on your hosting provider.

Comment: I have a doubt. If uploading can be done directly using HTTP as above then why some blogs have used volley or retrofit library. What's the difference between these methods?

Answer (score 9):

Try this: it 100% working copy.

Upload function:  (Parameter to a function is the imagePath)

```
public void uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


          String fileName = imagePath;
          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
          File sourceFile = new File(imagePath); 

          if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

                if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+imagePath);


          }
          else
          {
            try { 

               // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(Upload_Image_URL);

                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                  dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                  bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                  bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                  bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                 }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                  + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);


                //close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

           } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                    if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
               ex.printStackTrace();

               Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
           } catch (Exception e) {

               if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
               }
               e.printStackTrace();


           }

            if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

            }  


               } // End else block 
             }
```

Php Service:

```
  $file_path = "images/";
  $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
  echo "success";
  } else{ echo "fail";}
```

Must create a folder named "images" in the server so $file_path is valid

Comment: String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

Answer (score 2):

If you are using free hosting then the pages are getting redirected for tracking no. of hits. You probably receive Http Response :200 OK but you wont see file uploaded because file is lost.

I myself wasted 3 days searching for the solution but found nothing. Figured this out myself.

Answer (score 1):

Complete working code .... with PHP code

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private static final int PICK_FILE_REQUEST = 1;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private String selectedFilePath;
private String SERVER_URL = "http://Ip Address/a.php";
ImageView ivAttachment;
Button bUpload;
TextView tvFileName;
ProgressDialog dialog;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ivAttachment = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAttachment);
    bUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_upload);
    tvFileName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_file_name);
    ivAttachment.setOnClickListener(this);
    bUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v== ivAttachment){

        //on attachment icon click
        showFileChooser();
    }
    if(v== bUpload){

        //on upload button Click
        if(selectedFilePath != null){
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"","Uploading File...",true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //creating new thread to handle Http Operations
                    uploadFile(selectedFilePath);
                }
            }).start();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please choose a File First",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    //sets the select file to all types of files
    intent.setType("*/*");
    //allows to select data and return it
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    //starts new activity to select file and return data
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose File to Upload.."),PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST){
            if(data == null){
                //no data present
                return;
            }


            Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
            selectedFilePath = FilePath.getPath(this,selectedFileUri);
            Log.i(TAG,"Selected File Path:" + selectedFilePath);

            if(selectedFilePath != null && !selectedFilePath.equals("")){
                tvFileName.setText(selectedFilePath);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Cannot upload file to server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

//android upload file to server
public int uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath){

    int serverResponseCode = 0;

    HttpURLConnection connection;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";


    int bytesRead,bytesAvailable,bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);


    String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
    final String fileName = parts[parts.length-1];

    if (!selectedFile.isFile()){
        dialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tvFileName.setText("Source File Doesn't Exist: " + selectedFilePath);
            }
        });
        return 0;
    }else{
        try{
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);

            //creating new dataoutputstream
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            //writing bytes to data outputstream
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
            //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);

            //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
            while (bytesRead > 0){
                //write the bytes read from inputstream
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
            }

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
            if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvFileName.setText("File Upload completed.\n\n You can see the uploaded file here: \n\n" + "http://coderefer.com/extras/uploads/"+ fileName);
                    }
                });
            }

            //closing the input and output streams
            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"File Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "URL error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cannot Read/Write File!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;
    }

   }
   }
```

add FilePath.cs

```
public class FilePath {

public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    // check here to KITKAT or new version
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + split[1];
            }
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                    Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context
 *            The context.
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to query.
 * @param selection
 *            (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs
 *            (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
                                   String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = { column };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:id="@+id/tvHeading"
    android:text="Touch the icon below to upload file to server"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivAttachment"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_file_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ivAttachment"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/b_upload"
    android:text="Upload"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="#039be5"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

php file a.php

```
<?php
 if (isset($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"])) {

$name = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
$error = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'];

if (!empty($name)) {
    $location = './fileload/';

 if ( ! is_dir($location)) {
 mkdir($location);
 }

    if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
        echo 'Uploaded';
    }

} else {
    echo 'please choose a file';
}
}
 ?>
```

add read/write permission to the fileload folder

tested with fiddler with following code

```
  User-Agent: Fiddler
  Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=*****
  uploaded_file: C:\Desktop\oldScreen.png
  Content-Disposition: form-data; 
  name="uploaded_file";filename="C:\\Desktop\oldScreen.png"
  Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Php file

```
 <?php


 if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['bill']['tmp_name'])) {
$uploads_dir = 'Uploads/staff_documents/';
                        $tmp_name = $_FILES['bill']['tmp_name'];
                        $pic_name = $_FILES['bill']['name'];
                        echo $pic_name;
                        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir.$pic_name);
                        }
           else{
               echo "File not uploaded successfully.";
       }

?>
```

It supports All file
To upload docs from the android device you can make use of https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service
Because it gives notification support as well

Android Java Part

```
 new MultipartUploadRequest(getApplicationContext(), uploadId, "Your server 
 url")
                        .addFileToUpload(filePathURI + "","bill") 
                         //Adding file
                        .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                        .setMaxRetries(2)
                        .startUpload();
```

Answer (score 0):

These examples give an error on Nginx+HyperfastCGI+Mono. To remove the error, you need to put a space after the semicolon.

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
```

Maybe someone will need this information.

Answer (score 0):

Those who are looking for Kotlin solution, can use this utility class. Here is the detailed article I have written on the topic. It uses OKHTTP3.
[Upload File to Server in Android Kotlin](https://handyopinion.com/upload-file-to-server-in-android-kotlin/)

```
package com.mvp.handyopinion

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.ProgressDialog
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.Log
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap
import android.widget.Toast
import okhttp3.*
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaTypeOrNull
import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.asRequestBody
import java.io.File

class UploadUtility(activity: Activity) {

    var activity = activity;
    var dialog: ProgressDialog? = null
    var serverURL: String = "https://handyopinion.com/tutorials/UploadToServer.php"
    var serverUploadDirectoryPath: String = "https://handyopinion.com/tutorials/uploads/"
    val client = OkHttpClient()

    fun uploadFile(sourceFilePath: String, uploadedFileName: String? = null) {
        uploadFile(File(sourceFilePath), uploadedFileName)
    }

    fun uploadFile(sourceFileUri: Uri, uploadedFileName: String? = null) {
        val pathFromUri = URIPathHelper().getPath(activity,sourceFileUri)
        uploadFile(File(pathFromUri), uploadedFileName)
    }

    fun uploadFile(sourceFile: File, uploadedFileName: String? = null) {
        Thread {
            val mimeType = getMimeType(sourceFile);
            if (mimeType == null) {
                Log.e("file error", "Not able to get mime type")
                return@Thread
            }
            val fileName: String = if (uploadedFileName == null)  sourceFile.name else uploadedFileName
            toggleProgressDialog(true)
            try {
                val requestBody: RequestBody =
                    MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("uploaded_file", fileName,sourceFile.asRequestBody(mimeType.toMediaTypeOrNull()))
                        .build()

                val request: Request = Request.Builder().url(serverURL).post(requestBody).build()

                val response: Response = client.newCall(request).execute()

                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d("File upload","success, path: $serverUploadDirectoryPath$fileName")
                    showToast("File uploaded successfully at $serverUploadDirectoryPath$fileName")
                } else {
                    Log.e("File upload", "failed")
                    showToast("File uploading failed")
                }
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                ex.printStackTrace()
                Log.e("File upload", "failed")
                showToast("File uploading failed")
            }
            toggleProgressDialog(false)
        }.start()
    }

    // url = file path or whatever suitable URL you want.
    fun getMimeType(file: File): String? {
        var type: String? = null
        val extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.path)
        if (extension != null) {
            type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension)
        }
        return type
    }

    fun showToast(message: String) {
        activity.runOnUiThread {
            Toast.makeText( activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show()
        }
    }

    fun toggleProgressDialog(show: Boolean) {
        activity.runOnUiThread {
            if (show) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "", "Uploading file...", true);
            } else {
                dialog?.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }

}
```