# Upload image from Android camera with HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, bitmap, httpurlconnection, image-uploading

I have a restful web service, and i need to be able to send an image to it from Android via HttpUrlConnection.

Currently I am converting the image to a string as follows

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
String temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

And sending it in a request like so (Async obviously)

```
 url = new URL("blabla/users/1/updatePhoto/" + temp);

 connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
 connection.connect();
```

This is the error I get. I'm assuming the url is just too long to work, so I'm wondering if theres a better way to do this. Thanks

> java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{192.168.0.22:8080, proxy=DIRECT@hostAddress=192.168.0.22 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)

Comment: I do not understand why the image needs to be passed in url instead of post body

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction of how this can be done? And in my web service how can I consume both the user id and the image?

Comment: Simply put user id in post body, and for image using output stream

Comment: @S.W. I think my Android code is working now anyway, I'm sending a request using output stream  `OutputStream output = c.getOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, output);` How do I consume the request from my server? I'd know how to normally, but I'm not sure where to get the part that was sent with the output stream? (I'm using resteasy)

Comment: you may try follow this guide
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398200/uploading-file-in-php-server-from-android-device