# Uploading file to server NOT WORKING

Tags: java, php, android, httpurlconnection

> My code is below.
>
> After uploading (time is varying for different file sizes) I got 200 Ok and response

```
public class CloudFileUploader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {



@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(mFile);
        URL url = new URL(CloudConstants.getFileUploadBaseUrl());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary + ";key=fileToUpload");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        String contentLength=Long.toString(mFile.length());
 //            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",contentLength );

        AppSharedPreference mPref = new AppSharedPreference(mContext);
        String token = mPref.getStringPrefValue(PreferenceConstants.USER_TOKEN);
        conn.setRequestProperty("token", token);
        conn.setRequestProperty("groupId", "" + mMessage.getReceiverId());
        conn.setRequestProperty("message", "" + mMessage.getMessageBody());
        conn.setRequestProperty("messageType", "" + mMessage.getMessageType());
        conn.setRequestProperty("senderName", "" + mMessage.getSenderName());

        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myFile\";filename=\"" + mFile.getName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        Log.i(TAG, "Initial .available : " + bytesAvailable);

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException | FileNotFoundException | ProtocolException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
                    .getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (onFileUploadListener != null) {
                onFileUploadListener.onUploadFailed(mMessage, new AppError(ErrorHandler.ERROR_FROM_SERVER, ErrorHandler.ErrorMessage.ERROR_FROM_SERVER));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } else {
        return "Could not upload";
    }
}
}
```

I put `conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",contentLength );` but it will throw  java.net.ProtocolException.

I tested differnt code but the issue is still there.

> Below given is my php server script.

```
$status['apiId'] = _GROUP_FILE_UPLOAD_API;
    $user_id = $this->user['user_id'];
    $target_dir = ROOTDIR_PATH . DS . "data" . DS . "GroupFileUploads" . DS;
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
     $fileUpload = NULL;
    if ($this->headers->get('groupId')) {
        $fileUpload['groupId'] = $groupId = $this->headers->get('groupId')->getFieldValue();
    }
    if ($this->headers->get('messageType')) {
        $fileUpload['messageType'] = $messageType = $this->headers->get('messageType')->getFieldValue();
    } if ($this->headers->get('message')) {
        $fileUpload['message'] = $message = $this->headers->get('message')->getFieldValue();
    }
    if ($this->headers->get('senderName')) {
        $fileUpload['senderName'] = $senderName = $this->headers->get('senderName')->getFieldValue();
    }
```

The code is not working. It is not saving anything to the folder I given.

> But It is working from *Postman* and *AdvancedRestClient*
>
> When I put die() then i Got

`Array(    [myFile] => Array        (            [name] => 1495018448FaceApp_1494992050886.jpg            [type] =>             [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpH2kH47            [error] => 0            [size] => 917953        ))`

The `[type] =>` should be `image/jpg` but it is empty

Comment: Why are you not using [HttpClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126625/how-do-i-send-a-file-in-android-from-a-mobile-device-to-server-using-http)?

Comment: Hi @Godwin its possible duplicate. Kindly check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398200/uploading-file-in-php-server-from-android-device

Comment: Why do you put some text in quote blocks..?

Comment: It should be   dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

Comment: Do the flush before you ask for a response code. And do not close the output stream.

Comment: You catch a lot of exceptions. Which is good. But if you have one you just continue with the code as if nothing has happened. Instead you should return an error message there and display the message in onPostExecute.

Comment: @Rameshbabu yes Bro its the copy code, but its not working

Comment: @greenapps Oops its also not working. and in every example, they are not using `bytesToRead` instead of that they are using `bufferSize`  because the third paraaeter is length

Comment: That parameter will not make it work i know. But if you get it to work then you will see that you have to use bytesRead as you should specify the amount of bytes to be written. Which is bytesRead. Dont write more bytes then you read. And all examples are wrong of course.

Comment: What about the flush and the close?

Comment: Its is not the byte array or buffersize , All are fine when I put die on php, then I got the file name and properties but the type is bot printing