# Upload file .csr to web server using Android

Tags: android

I write the code using android to write Certificate Signing Request to file .csr and store in external.

```
                String state;
                state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

                if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
                {
                    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath()+"/MyAppFile1");
                    if(!dir.exists())
                    {
                        dir.mkdir();
                    }
                    File file = new File(dir,"ecc.csr");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                        PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(writer);
                        pemWriter.writeObject(new PemObject("CERTIFICATE REQUEST", CSRder));
                        pemWriter.flush();
                        pemWriter.close();
                        String csrPEM = writer.toString();
                        fileOutputStream.write(csrPEM.getBytes());
                        fileOutputStream.close();

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SAVE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NO SD CARD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

And here is file path when I use toast.
[image: Here is file path]

Now I want to upload this .csr file to my webserver (PHP). I have to refer some guide like this ([Guide 1](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83)) or ([Guide 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398200/uploading-file-in-php-server-from-android-device)) then write again, but it not work. I jump to Exception

```
Got Exception : see logcat
```

And log is:

```
6.998 20228-31551/com.example.napoleon.hocuploadfile3 E/Upload file to server Exception: Exception : /storage/emulated/0/MyAppFile1/ecc.csr (Permission denied)
                                                                                                  java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/MyAppFile1/ecc.csr (Permission denied)
                                                                                                      at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
                                                                                                      at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
                                                                                                      at com.example.napoleon.hocuploadfile3.MainActivity.upLoadFile(MainActivity.java:90)
                                                                                                      at com.example.napoleon.hocuploadfile3.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:19)
                                                                                                      at com.example.napoleon.hocuploadfile3.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:50)
                                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Here is my manifest content:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
final  String uploadFilePath = "/storage/emulated/0/MyAppFile1/";
final  String uploadFileName = "ecc.csr";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    upLoadServerUri = "http://192.168.1.104/UploadToServer.php";

    btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
    txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"","Uploading...",true);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            txtMessage.setText("Uploading....");
                        }
                    });
                    upLoadFile(uploadFilePath+""+uploadFileName);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });

}

private int upLoadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
    if(!sourceFile.isFile())
    {
        dialog.dismiss();

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                txtMessage.setText("Source File not exist :"
                        +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
            }
        });

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        try{
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        String msg = "File Upload Completed";

                        txtMessage.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        }
        catch(MalformedURLException ex)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    txtMessage.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    txtMessage.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                    + ex.getMessage(), ex);

        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;
    }

}

}
```

I looking for help, anyway to upload file to web server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 08-06 22:49:06.998 20228-31551/com.example.napoleon.hocuploadfile3 E/Upload file to server Exception: Exception : /storage/emulated/0/MyAppFile1/ecc.csr (Permission denied)
                                                                                                      java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/MyAppFile1/ecc.csr (Permission denied)

Comment: And webserver I use Wamp in windows

Comment: I have edit my question, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to your ansroid.manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

On SDK >= 23 you need to check and then ask for permission:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```

To do proper checking of SD Card:

```
if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) && Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()) {
}
```

Comment: Oh, I use SDK 24, let me try. Thanks.

Comment: No, no I have SD card. I have checked. I have user-permission but I use SDK 24, I must go to setting and turn on it. User permission in manifest is not enough.