# Send parameters while uploading file to PHP source

Tags: java, php, android, http

I'm using this class to upload image to php server from my android app.

But I want to send some parameters such as custom file name, user who uploaded the file etc.

Is there any way to send some parameters while uploading the file?

Example: name=newimage&uploadedby=username

```
private class UploadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        String sourceFileUri = "/mnt/sdcard/abc.png";

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

        if (sourceFile.isFile()) {

            try {
                String upLoadServerUri = "http://website.com/abc.php?";

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                        sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE",
                        "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("bill", sourceFileUri);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"bill\";filename=\""
                        + sourceFileUri + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math
                            .min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,
                            bufferSize);

                }

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                        + lineEnd);

                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn
                        .getResponseMessage();

                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                    //Toast.makeText(ctx, "File Upload Complete.",
                    //      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                }

                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Executed";
}

}
```

Is there any way to do this with header request, like this:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("parameters","name=filename&uploadedby=username");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading file in php server from android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398200/uploading-file-in-php-server-from-android-device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible

I am not a java developer but in PHP you can receive such data in 2 ways: as parameter in the URL which will be available in PHP in the $_GET array
Example, change your URL to:

`String upLoadServerUri = "http://website.com/abc.php?filename=blabla&anotherparam=1234";`

then in PHP:  `echo $_GET['filename']`. $_GET is also available if you are POSTing your request.

or/and you can do this in your POST. Your POST request can contain as many extra params as you need. [Here is an example](http://www.riptutorial.com/android/example/12202/sending-an-http-post-request-with-parameters) how you could do this.