# Android-PHP error undefined index Error raised

Tags: php, android, rest, api, android-studio

I want to upload image from android app but it generate error of Undefined Index:user_pic in xampp\htdocs\CityHero\user_registration.php on line 13...
I can't understand what is the problem related to this error..
user_registration.php

```
    <?php
require "config.php";

$obj = new config();

$er = 0;
$filename = ""; 

$return = array();

if (isset($_POST["user_name"]) && isset($_POST["user_email"]) && isset($_POST["user_city"]) && isset($_POST["user_area"]) && isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {

    if ($_FILES['user_pic']["name"] != "") {
        $type = "." . pathinfo($_FILES['user_pic']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if ($type == ".jpeg" || $type == ".png" || $type == ".jpg" || $type == ".bmp") {
            $filename = date("d-m-Y-H-i-s").$type;
            $file_server_path = $obj->SERVERPATH . basename($filename);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_pic']['tmp_name'], $file_server_path);

            $return["STATUS"] = true;
            $return["MSG"] = "FILE UPLOADED SUCCESSFULLY...";
        }else{
            $er = 1;
            echo "Error!!!Please Check Code Once Again....";
            // echo $return["STATUS"] = false;
            // echo $return["MSG"] = "ERROR!!! Please Check Code once again....";
        }

        if ($er == 0) {
            $insData["user_name"] = $_POST["user_name"];
            $insData["user_email"] = $_POST["user_email"];
            $insData["user_city"] = $_POST["user_city"];
            $insData["user_area"] = $_POST["user_area"];
            $insData["username"] = $_POST["username"];
            $insData["password"] = md5($_POST["password"]);
            $insData["create_date"] = $obj->current_date;
            $insData["modify_date"] = $obj->current_date;
            $insData["remote_ip"] = $obj->remote_ip;
            $insData["user_pic"] = $filename;

            $result = $obj->myInsdata("users_registration",$insData);

            if ($result) {
                echo "Insertion Succesfull";
                // echo $return["STATUS"] = true;
                // echo $return["MSG"] = "INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY...";                
            }else{
                echo "Error!!!Please Check Code Once Again....";
                // echo $return["STATUS"] = false;
                // echo $return["MSG"] = "INSERTED NOT SUCCESSFULL...";     
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "Error!!!Please Check Code Once Again....";
    // echo $return["STATUS"] = false;
    // echo $return["MSG"] = "FIELD IS NOT SET..";      
}

//echo json_encode($return);
```

?>

**And here is my Android Studio Upload Code..**

```
  package com.example.acer.jsonparsing;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText fname,femail,fcity,farea,fusername,password,path;

    Button insert,upload;

    String insertURL = "http://192.168.2.76/CityHero/user_registration.php";

    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    String encodedImage;

    Bitmap bitmap;

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fname);
        femail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        fcity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.city);
        farea = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.area);
        fusername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
        upload=(Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadimage);
        insert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.insertdata);
        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent=new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,123);
            }
        });


        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
                        String imageData = encodedImage;
                        parameters.put("user_name",fname.getText().toString());
                        parameters.put("user_email",femail.getText().toString());
                        parameters.put("user_city",fcity.getText().toString());
                        parameters.put("user_area",farea.getText().toString());
                        parameters.put("username",fusername.getText().toString());
                        parameters.put("password",password.getText().toString());
                        parameters.put("user_pic",encodedImage);
                        return parameters;
                    }
                };
                requestQueue.add(request);
            }
        });
    }

    private String getImageString(Bitmap bitmap ){
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputStream);
        byte[] imagebyte = outputStream.toByteArray();

        encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imagebyte,Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case 123:
                Uri imageuri = data.getData();

                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),imageuri);
                    getImageString(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Please Help me how can i upload image from Android Application to Mysql database...**

Comment: you should pass a `File` naming `user_pic`

Comment: At which place..?

Comment: you need `Multipart`  to upload File to sever.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398200/uploading-file-in-php-server-from-android-device) it will help you.

Comment: ok....is there any other way to upload image on server?

Comment: posted answer. check if that helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload pic using [Gotev Upload Service](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service)

In gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {  
   implementation "net.gotev:uploadservice:3.4.2"
}
```

Then in Activity

```
public void uploadMultipart(final Context context) {    
    try {  
        String uploadId =  
                new MultipartUploadRequest(context, "your URL here")  
                        .addFileToUpload("data.getData() here", "user_pic")                           
                        .addParameter("user_name", "param value") 
                        .addParameter("user_email", "param value") 
                        .addParameter("user_city", "param value") 
                        .addParameter("user_area", "param value") 
                        .addParameter("username", "param value")  
                        .addParameter("password", "param value")        
                        .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())  
                            .setMaxRetries(2)  
                            .startUpload();  

        } catch (Exception exc) {  
            Toast.makeText(context, "Exception: "+exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        }  
    }
```