# how to send image from android to server(laravel)

Tags: java, php, android, laravel

i searched in internet .i can't found a solution(that updated) !
I‘m wanna uploading one image or two or more in server (Laravel) but i don‘t know that in android image or images  must convert will be to what  format(standard way)?
what is best way for store image/images after will have sent from android to Laravel?

Comment: you can have a look at solutions provided here on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398200/uploading-file-in-php-server-from-android-device

Comment: ok i see it but it is for 4 years ago.in your idea this way after 4 years without changed yet?

Comment: If the code currently work with Your implementation IDE without bugs then you are good to go. Years may not be a priority

Comment: I still work with some solutions on stackoverflow that were implemented 8 years back and they are still the same upto date. I just keep on researching and making sure am always on top of modern trends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally images and files are sent to the server as multipart file. You may use libraries like Volley, Retrofit for such kind of operations.