# How to send a file from my android application to my php mysql server

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I made an android application for sending files like .pdf .ppt .jpeg .png etc to php mysql server. I tried several 3rd party file picking libraries , but none worked in my android device (android q).

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Please Select a file"), 1);
```

By this I can utmost get the file's content Uri but i am unable to use it to send it to server. Please help.

Comment: Well.. to send a file you dont need a file picker i would say. You need some upload code.

Comment: Further: a file is a file. If you can send one file you can send any file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56308643/115145

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading file in php server from android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398200/uploading-file-in-php-server-from-android-device)

Comment: No that is only for images. I am not getting the file path of other files by that method