# Upload Document Android App - Android Studio

Tags: android

I am developing an app in android studio. I need to write code for a document to be uploaded. For instance, a user logs in and has the option to upload a document or other sort of file.  I am pretty new to mobile development so I searched the internet and didn't find much.

Comment: look at my post bellow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [file upload using httppost android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138881/file-upload-using-httppost-android)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
      String fileName = sourceFileUri;

      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;  
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
      File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

      if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

           dialog.dismiss(); 

           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                               +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                           +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
               }
           }); 

           return 0;

      }
      else
      {
           try { 

                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file";filename=""
                                         + fileName + """ + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                          +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                          +uploadFileName;

                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });                
               }    

               //close the streams //
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              ex.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException", 
                                                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

              Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
          } catch (Exception e) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              e.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
              Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                               + e.getMessage(), e);  
          }
          dialog.dismiss();       
          return serverResponseCode; 

       } // End else block 
     }
```

As mentioned here:

[Original Article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22139271/3871208)

You might want to visit the link to download the jar.

Comment: Error:(25, 0) Could not find property 'file' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@6cd14b86.     <= I received that error when I tried to build my gradle files