# Java get upload POST file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I am working on a project which can upload files from a local PC Web-browser ( Chrome or IE ) to phone web-server.

I some how managed to upload file to server and the code goes like this

```
$.ajax({
        url: loc,
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (res) 
        {
                $.prompt("File uploaded", 
            {
                buttons : 
                {
                    "OK" : true
                },
                callback : refreshFileCallback
            }); 
        }
    });
```

But

> How do I get the uploaded file send through POST in java?

**Webserver code**

```
package org.join.wfs.server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultHttpResponseFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultHttpServerConnection;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreConnectionPNames;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestHandlerRegistry;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ResponseConnControl;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ResponseContent;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ResponseDate;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ResponseServer;

public class WebServer extends Thread 
{

    static final String SUFFIX_ZIP = "..zip";
    static final String SUFFIX_DEL = "..del";
    static final String SUFFIX_REN = "..ren";
    static final String SUFFIX_NEW_FOLDER = "..new";
    static final String SUFFIX_CREATE_FILE = "..cre";
    static final String SUFFIX_MORE = "..mor";
    static final String SUFFIX_UPLOAD = "..upl";

    private int port;
    private String webRoot;
    private boolean isLoop = false;

    public WebServer(int port, final String webRoot) 
    {
        super();
        this.port = port;
        this.webRoot = webRoot;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try 
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            BasicHttpProcessor httpproc = new BasicHttpProcessor();
            httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseDate());
            httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseServer());
            httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseContent());
            httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseConnControl());

            HttpService httpService = new HttpService(httpproc, new DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy(), new DefaultHttpResponseFactory());

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 5000)
                  .setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE,8 * 1024)
                  .setBooleanParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.STALE_CONNECTION_CHECK, false)
                  .setBooleanParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                  .setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.ORIGIN_SERVER,"WebServer/1.1");

            httpService.setParams(params);

            HttpRequestHandlerRegistry reqistry = new HttpRequestHandlerRegistry();

            reqistry.register("*" + SUFFIX_ZIP, new HttpZipHandler(webRoot));
            reqistry.register("*" + SUFFIX_DEL, new HttpDelHandler(webRoot));
            reqistry.register("*" + SUFFIX_REN, new HttpRenameHandler(webRoot));
            reqistry.register("*" + SUFFIX_NEW_FOLDER, new HttpNewFolderHandler(webRoot));
            reqistry.register("*" + SUFFIX_CREATE_FILE, new HttpCreateFileHandler(webRoot));
            reqistry.register("*" + SUFFIX_MORE, new HttpMoreHandler(webRoot));
            reqistry.register("*" + SUFFIX_UPLOAD, new HttpUploadFileHandler(webRoot));
            reqistry.register("*", new HttpFileHandler(webRoot));

            httpService.setHandlerResolver(reqistry);

            isLoop = true;
            while (isLoop && !Thread.interrupted()) 
            {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                DefaultHttpServerConnection conn = new DefaultHttpServerConnection();
                conn.bind(socket, params);
                Thread t = new WorkerThread(httpService, conn);
                t.setDaemon(true);
                t.start();
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            isLoop = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                if (serverSocket != null) 
                {
                    serverSocket.close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public void close() 
    {
        isLoop = false;
    }

}
```

if not possible , please suggest me another method on how to upload file from HTML to java

Thankyou

Comment: What  are you using on server side jsp-servlet or spring???

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017414/post-multipart-request-with-android-sdk

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP is trying to upload a file from a desktop web browser to a web server running on an Android phone.

OP: how have you implemented the web server on the phone?

Comment: i think he is going to upload file from AJAX to default android server ......