# how to send multiple part form http request on java (Android)

Tags: android, http, networking

Does http in Android has a multiple-part-form-request  just like the `multipartFormRequestWithMethod` in AFNetWorking lib from Objective-c? I am using https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request

I wonder how to send multipart http request on Android. Any ideas, thanks in advance.

### EDIT

I am using this way, adding several jars as suggested by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017414/post-multipart-request-with-android-sdk/22803149#22803149), but turns out it fails somewhere, any ideas?

```
private void uploadBlocksCommit(String commiturl, boolean update, String _uploadpath, String name, int fileSize, List<String> allblocks) throws IOException {
    HttpRequest req = prepareApiPostRequest(commiturl, true, null);
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    builder.addTextBody("csrfmiddlewaretoken", "n8ba38951c9ba66418311a25195e2e380");
    if (update) {
        builder.addTextBody("replace", "1");
    }
    builder.addTextBody("parent_dir", _uploadpath);
    builder.addTextBody("file_name", name);
    builder.addTextBody("file_size", String.valueOf(fileSize));
    builder.addTextBody("csrfmiddlewaretoken", "n8ba38951c9ba66418311a25195e2e380");
    builder.addTextBody("blockids", allblocks.toString()); // don`t assemble strings in allblocks
    HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
    req.send(entity.getContent());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a interface using retrofit library 1.9

```
public interface upload_file {

@Multipart
@POST("/docupload/")
//public void uploadFile(@Header("Authorization") String auth,@Part("file") File photoFile,@Part("id") Integer familyMemberId,@Part("super_id") Integer super_id, Callback<UploadImageResponse> callback);
public void uploadFile(@Header("Authorization") String auth,@Part("file") TypedFile photoFile,@Part("id") Integer familyMemberId,@Part("file_desc") String filename,@Part("pin")String pin, Callback<String> callback);
```

}

and from your activity. Also convert you file into typed file object.

```
 RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).setEndpoint(API).build();
    //TypedFile typedFile = new TypedFile("*/*",new File(filePath));
    TypedFile typedFile = new TypedFile("*/*", new File(resultPath));
    upload_file hit_Api = restAdapter.create(upload_file.class);
    hit_Api.uploadFile(bearer, typedFile, mFamilyMemberIdSelected, mUserEnteredFileName, mUserSavedPin,new
            Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void success(String s, Response response) {


                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use, **Android Upload Service**

[image]

Easily upload files in the background with automatic Android Notification Center progress indication.

**Purpose**

- upload files to a server with HTTP `multipart/form-data` or binary requests
- handle uploads in the background, even if the device is idle
- automatically retry failed uploads, with an exponential backoff
- possibility to automatically delete successfully uploaded files from the device
- show status in the Android Notification Center.

**Setup**

**Maven**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.gotev</groupId>
  <artifactId>uploadservice</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
  <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.0.1@aar'
}
```

[Reference link.](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service)