# Using web api I want to upload image from mobile and down load from server

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api

I want to upload image from mobile to server , and download image from server to mobile (Android phone) .   I am using restful api service . can any one help me out on this . I have been trying on this solution since one week  .  I tried with below code "http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/uploading-image-to-server-using-web-api-2-0/" , But, not sure how I can achieve from android phone
Thanks,

Shuhaib

Comment: Incredible. Both topics are covered nearly every day again here on stackoverflow. If you only started reading a couple of pages tagged `android`.

Comment: please search on uploading multipart files in android. there are a lot of tutorials out there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post multipart request with Android SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017414/post-multipart-request-with-android-sdk)