# How to send image by multipart?

Tags: android, base64

I used to send by Base64

```
 Observable.fromCallable {
                val sampledBitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromFilePath(photoPath, 500, 500)
                File(photoPath).delete()
                bitmapToBase64(sampledBitmap)
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

Now I want to substitute **bitmapToBase64** to **MULTIPART ENCODING**

Comment: which library you are using for api calls?

Comment: retrofit used for api calls

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22803149/1939564

Comment: @KaranMer retrofit